# best way to implement custom pretty-printers

Tags: python, xml, subclass, pretty-print, docbook

## Customizing `pprint.PrettyPrinter`

The documentation for the `pprint` module mentions that the method `PrettyPrinter.format` is intended to make it possible to customize formatting.

I gather that it's possible to override this method in a subclass, but this doesn't seem to provide a way to have the base class methods apply line wrapping and indentation.

- Am I missing something here?
- Is there a better way to do this (e.g. another module)?

### Alternatives?

I've checked out the [`pretty`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pretty/0.1) module, which looks interesting, but doesn't seem to provide a way to customize formatting of classes from other modules without modifying those modules.

I think what I'm looking for is something that would allow me to provide a mapping of types (or maybe functions) that identify types to routines that process a node.  The routines that process a node would take a node and return the string representation it, along with a list of child nodes.  And so on.

### Why I’m looking into pretty-printing

My end goal is to compactly print custom-formatted sections of a DocBook-formatted `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

(I was surprised to not find more Python support for DocBook. Maybe I missed something there.)

I built some basic functionality into a client called [xmlearn](http://github.com/intuited/xmlearn) that uses [lxml](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml).  For example, to dump a Docbook file, you could:

```
xmlearn -i docbook_file.xml dump -f docbook -r book
```

It's pretty half-ass, but it got me the info I was looking for.

[xmlearn](http://github.com/intuited/xmlearn) has other features too, like the ability to build a graph image and do dumps showing the relationships between tags in an XML document.  These are pretty much totally unrelated to this question.

You can also perform a dump to an arbitrary depth, or specify an XPath as a set of starting points.  The XPath stuff sort of obsoleted the docbook-specific format, so that isn't really well-developed.

This still isn't really an answer for the question. I'm still hoping that there's a readily customizable pretty printer out there somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

My solution was to replace pprint.PrettyPrinter with a simple wrapper that formats any floats it finds before calling the original printer.

```
from __future__ import division
import pprint
if not hasattr(pprint,'old_printer'):
    pprint.old_printer=pprint.PrettyPrinter

class MyPrettyPrinter(pprint.old_printer):
    def _format(self,obj,*args,**kwargs):
        if isinstance(obj,float):
            obj=round(obj,4)
        return pprint.old_printer._format(self,obj,*args,**kwargs)
pprint.PrettyPrinter=MyPrettyPrinter

def pp(obj):
    pprint.pprint(obj)

if __name__=='__main__':
    x=[1,2,4,6,457,3,8,3,4]
    x=[_/17 for _ in x]
    pp(x)
```

Answer (score 3):

*This question may be a duplicate of:*

- [Any way to properly pretty-print ordered dictionaries in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301069/any-way-to-properly-pretty-print-ordered-dictionaries-in-python)

---

## Using `pprint.PrettyPrinter`

I looked through the [source of pprint](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/pprint.py?view=markup). It seems to suggest that, in order to enhance `pprint()`, you’d need to:

- subclass `PrettyPrinter`
- override `_format()`
- test for `issubclass()`,
- and (if it's not your class), pass back to `_format()`

## Alternative

I think a better approach would be just to have your own `pprint()`, which defers to `pprint.pformat` when it doesn't know what's up.

For example:

```python
'''Extending pprint'''

from pprint import pformat

class CrazyClass: pass

def prettyformat(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, CrazyClass):
        return "^CrazyFoSho^"
    else:
        return pformat(obj)

def prettyp(obj):
    print(prettyformat(obj))

# test
prettyp([1]*100)
prettyp(CrazyClass())
```

The big upside here is that you don't depend on `pprint` internals. It’s explicit and concise.

The downside is that you’ll have to take care of indentation manually.

Comment: Another downside of **Alternative** is that `prettyp([CrazyClass()])` won't work.

Comment: See this patch, which was applied to Python quite some time ago: http://bugs.python.org/issue1373762 This allows you to subclass PrettyPrinter and override `format`. An example is given in the text. Note that the example is flawed because `True` and `False` will be printed as `0x1` and `0x0`, which hides the fact that they are `bool`.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to modify the default pretty printer without subclassing, you can use the internal `_dispatch` table on the `pprint.PrettyPrinter` class. You can see how examples of how dispatching is added for internal types like dictionaries and lists [in the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pprint.py#L180-L192).

Here is how I added a custom pretty printer for [MatchPy's Operation](https://matchpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/matchpy.expressions.expressions.html#matchpy.expressions.expressions.Operation) type:

```
import pprint
import matchpy

def _pprint_operation(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level):
    """
    Modified from pprint dict https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/pprint.py#L194
    """
    operands = object.operands
    if not operands:
        stream.write(repr(object))
        return
    cls = object.__class__
    stream.write(cls.__name__ + "(")
    self._format_items(
        operands, stream, indent + len(cls.__name__), allowance + 1, context, level
    )
    stream.write(")")


pprint.PrettyPrinter._dispatch[matchpy.Operation.__repr__] = _pprint_operation
```

Now if I use `pprint.pprint` on any object that has the same `__repr__` as `matchpy.Operation`, it will use this method to pretty print it. This works on subclasses as well, as long as they don't override the `__repr__`, which makes some sense! If you have the same `__repr__` you have the same pretty printing behavior.

Here is an example of the pretty printing some MatchPy operations now:

```
ReshapeVector(Vector(Scalar('1')),
              Vector(Index(Vector(Scalar('0')),
                           If(Scalar('True'),
                              Scalar("ReshapeVector(Vector(Scalar('2'), Scalar('2')), Iota(Scalar('10')))"),
                              Scalar("ReshapeVector(Vector(Scalar('2'), Scalar('2')), Ravel(Iota(Scalar('10'))))")))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `pretty` module:

- http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pretty/0.1

Comment: an improved and maintained version that supports Python 3.x can be found in IPython (as IPython.lib.pretty): http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.pretty.html

Comment: This answer is link-only, you should expand the answer to explain how should the module be used.