# Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict?

Tags: python, json, load, ordereddictionary

Ok so I can use an OrderedDict in `json.dump`. That is, an OrderedDict can be used as an input to JSON.

But can it be used as an output? If so how? In my case I'd like to `load` into an OrderedDict so I can keep the order of the keys in the file.

If not, is there some kind of workaround?

Comment: Yes, in my case I am bridging the gap between different languages and applications, and JSON works very well. But the ordering of keys is a bit of an issue. Would be awesome to have a simple to tick in `json.load` to use OrderedDicts instead of Dicts in Python.

Comment: That is pretty annoying.  In Javascript (of which json is a subset) order of keys is also not preserved...

Comment: JSON spec defines object type as having unordered keys... expecting specific key order is a mistake

Comment: Key ordering isn't usually for any sort of functional requirements.  It's mainly just for human readability.  If I just want my json to be pretty-printed, I do not expect any of the document order to change at all.

Comment: It also helps avoid large git diffs!

Comment: **See also:** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43789439

Answer (score 670, accepted):

Yes, you can.  By specifying the `object_pairs_hook` argument to [JSONDecoder](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders).  In fact, this is the exact example given in the documentation.

```
>>> json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict).decode('{"foo":1, "bar": 2}')
OrderedDict([('foo', 1), ('bar', 2)])
>>>
```

You can pass this parameter to `json.loads` (if you don't need a Decoder instance for other purposes) like so:

```
>>> import json
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = json.loads('{"foo":1, "bar": 2}', object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
>>> print json.dumps(data, indent=4)
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
}
>>>
```

Using `json.load` is done in the same way:

```
>>> data = json.load(open('config.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Comment: I am perplexed. The docs say the object_pairs_hook gets called for each literal that gets decoded into pairs. Why doesn't this create a new OrderedDict for each record in the JSON?

Comment: Hmm... the docs are somewhat ambiguously phrased.  What they mean as that the "whole result of decoding all the pairs" will be passed, in order, as a list, to `object_pairs_hook`, rather than "each pair will be passed to object_pairs_hook,"

Comment: But is loses the original order of the input json?

Comment: Was surprised to see that `json.load` does not keep it ordered by default, but looks like it is only mirroring what json itself does - the `{}` are unordered, but the `[]` in the json *are* ordered as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214316/4288043)

Comment: Does adding the OrderedDict hook keep the orders in dict in deeper hierarchy?

Comment: @RandomCertainty yes, every time a JSON object is encountered while parsing source, `OrderedDict` will be used to build up the resulting python value.

Comment: Thank you.  This solves my problem.  Only, ```data = json.load(open('config.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)```  works for me though.  The others do not work.  I am using Ubuntu 18.04 with Python 2.7.15+

Answer (score 129):

Simple version for Python 2.7+

```
my_ordered_dict = json.loads(json_str, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```

Or for Python 2.4 to 2.6

```
import simplejson as json
import ordereddict

my_ordered_dict = json.loads(json_str, object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
```

Comment: Ahhh, but it doesn't include the the object_pairs_hook -- which is why you still need simplejson in 2.6.  ;)

Comment: Want to note that `simplejson` and `ordereddict` are separate libraries that you need to install.

Comment: for python 2.7+: "import json, collections" in code, for python2.6- "aptitude install python-pip" and "pip install ordereddict" in the system

Comment: This is much more easyier and fast forward than previous method with JSONDecoder.

Comment: Oddly, in pypy, the included json will fail to `loads('{}', object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)`.

Comment: @mjhm any reason I would receive a TypeError: 'OrderedDict' object is not callable?

Comment: @Mike -- Not AFAIK, though I haven't looked at this in a long time.

Comment: @Mike - maybe you are adding an extra pair of parentheses?  It should be `object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict`, not `object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict()`

Comment: FYI centos-6 has an older version of python-simplejson v2.0.9 which does not have the required "object_pairs_hook". So a workaround/hack is to use json.dumps of your ordered dictionary object's pairs `collections.OrderedDict(json.loads(json.dumps(x.items())))`.

Comment: But is loses the original order of the input json?

Answer (score 51):

Some great news! Since version 3.6 the cPython implementation has preserved the insertion order of dictionaries (https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html). This means that the json library is now order preserving by default. Observe the difference in behaviour between python 3.5 and 3.6. The code:

```
import json
data = json.loads('{"foo":1, "bar":2, "fiddle":{"bar":2, "foo":1}}')
print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
```

In py3.5 the resulting order is undefined:

```
{
    "fiddle": {
        "bar": 2,
        "foo": 1
    },
    "bar": 2,
    "foo": 1
}
```

In the cPython implementation of python 3.6:

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2,
    "fiddle": {
        "bar": 2,
        "foo": 1
    }
}
```

The really great news is that this has become a language specification as of python 3.7 (as opposed to an implementation detail of cPython 3.6+): https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

So the answer to your question now becomes: upgrade to python 3.6! :)

Comment: Although I see the same behavior as you in the given example, in the CPython implementation of Python 3.6.4, `json.loads('{"2": 2, "1": 1}')` becomes `{'1': 1, '2': 2}` for me.

Comment: @fuglede it looks like `dict.__repr__` sorts keys while the underlying ordering is preserved. In other words, `json.loads('{"2": 2, "1": 1}').items()` is `dict_items([('2', 2), ('1', 1)])` even if `repr(json.loads('{"2": 2, "1": 1}'))` is `"{'1': 1, '2': 2}"`.

Comment: @SimonCharette Hm, could be; I'm actually unable to reproduce my own observation in conda's pkgs/main/win-64::python-3.6.4-h0c2934d_3, so this will be tough to test.

Comment: This doesn't really help much though, since "renaming" keys will still ruin the order of keys.

Comment: [Python documentation link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) -- The documentation mentions that "Starting with Python 3.7, the regular dict became order preserving, so it is no longer necessary to specify `collections.OrderedDict` for JSON generation and parsing.", which implies that by default the load inserts into the `dict` in the correct order.

Comment: @fuglede: That sounds like you were using an IPython version that sorts dict keys for display. (It's definitely not `dict.__repr__` - that doesn't sort in any Python version.)

Answer (score 8):

The normally used load command will work if you specify the **object_pairs_hook** parameter:

```
import json
from  collections import OrderedDict
with open('foo.json', 'r') as fp:
    metrics_types = json.load(fp, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Answer (score 7):

You could always write out the list of keys in addition to dumping the dict, and then reconstruct the `OrderedDict` by iterating through the list?

Comment: +1 for low-tech solution. I've done that when dealing with the same issue with YAML, but having to duplicate is kinda lame, especially when the underlying format preserves order. Might also make sense to avoid losing key-value pairs that are in the dict but missing from the list of keys, tacking them on after all the explicitly ordered items.

Comment: The low tech solution also preserves context that isn't otherwise necessarily preserved in the exported format (IOW; someone sees JSON and there's nothing there explicitly stating "these keys should remain in this order" if they do manipulations on it).

Comment: What determines that the list of keys "dumped" are in the right order? What about nested dicts? Seems like both the dumping would need to handle that and the reconstruction would need to be done recursively using `OrdereDict`s.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to dumping the ordered list of keys alongside the dictionary, another low-tech solution, which has the advantage of being explicit, is to dump the (ordered) list of key-value pairs `ordered_dict.items()`; loading is a simple `OrderedDict(<list of key-value pairs>)`. This handles an ordered dictionary despite the fact that JSON does not have this concept (JSON dictionaries have no order).

It is indeed nice to take advantage of the fact that `json` dumps the OrderedDict in the correct order. However, it is in general unnecessarily heavy and not necessarily meaningful to have to read *all* JSON dictionaries as an OrderedDict (through the `object_pairs_hook` argument), so an explicit conversion of *only* the dictionaries that must be ordered makes sense too.