# Is the order of elements in a JSON list preserved?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, list

I've noticed the order of elements in a JSON object not being the original order.

What about the elements of JSON lists? Is their order maintained?

Answer (score 485, accepted):

Yes, the order of elements in JSON arrays is preserved. From [RFC 7159 -The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.html)
 (emphasis mine):

> An object is an **unordered** collection of zero or more name/value
> pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
> boolean, null, object, or array.
>
> An array is an **ordered** sequence of zero or more values.
>
> The terms "object" and "array" come from the conventions of
> JavaScript.

Some implementations do also preserve the order of JSON objects as well, but this is not guaranteed.

Comment: However, I've spoken to some developers who have encountered problems where arrays are NOT ordered.  Take a look at this oddly worded passage in http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf     'The JSON syntax does not define any specific meaning to the ordering of the values.  However, the JSON array structure is often used in situations where there is some semantics to the ordering. '

Comment: @Cato that passage does not mean that arrays may be unordered. It means that the reason for ordering an array may be unknown, because you do not specify why it is ordered.

Answer (score 110):

The order of elements in an array (`[]`) is maintained.  The order of elements (name:value pairs) in an "object" (`{}`) is not, and it's usual for them to be "jumbled", if not by the JSON formatter/parser itself then by the language-specific objects (Dictionary, NSDictionary, Hashtable, etc) that are used as an internal representation.

Comment: Is this mentioned somewhere in "RFC 7159 -The JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) Data Interchange Format" or where did you obtain this information?

Comment: @hfrmobile - I learned it while developing the JSON package for the IBM I-Series computer line.

Answer (score 12):

Practically speaking, if the keys were of type NaN, the browser will not change the order.

The following script will output "One", "Two", "Three":

```
var foo={"3":"Three", "1":"One", "2":"Two"};
for(bar in foo) {
    alert(foo[bar]);
}
```

Whereas the following script will output "Three", "One", "Two":

```
var foo={"@3":"Three", "@1":"One", "@2":"Two"};
for(bar in foo) {
    alert(foo[bar]);
}
```

Comment: But that's relying on undefined behavior on the part of JSON. Anything you interchange with may not have the same behavior.

Comment: This answer discusses an object.  The question relates to json "list", which can only be inferred to mean array, which is semantically ordered by json specification (see Jeremy's answer).

Answer (score 8):

Some JavaScript engines keep keys in insertion order. V8, for instance, [keeps all keys in insertion order except for keys that can be parsed as unsigned 32-bit integers](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164#c1).

This means that if you run either of the following:

```
var animals = {};
animals['dog'] = true;
animals['bear'] = true;
animals['monkey'] = true;
for (var animal in animals) {
  if (animals.hasOwnProperty(animal)) {
    $('<li>').text(animal).appendTo('#animals');
  }
}
```

```
var animals = JSON.parse('{ "dog": true, "bear": true, "monkey": true }');
for (var animal in animals) {
  $('<li>').text(animal).appendTo('#animals');
}
```

You'll consistently get *dog*, *bear*, and *monkey* in that order, on Chrome, which uses V8. Node.js also uses V8. This will hold true even if you have thousands of items. YMMV with other JavaScript engines.

Demo [here](http://jsbin.com/amorip) and [here](http://jsbin.com/amorip/6/).

Comment: But that's relying on undefined behavior on the part of JSON.  Anything you interchange with may not have the same behavior.

Comment: It may work for small objects. It's quite reasonable to have an object implementation that stores the first three key/value pairs in an array, and switches to a hash table when the fourth entry is added. Or when your endusers have one more item than you ever tested.

Comment: That's an object, right? The question was about lists.

Comment: @PePa this is an old question. Don't do that, please.

Comment: @BenjaminAtkin This question still shows up in search results, this page is still accessible. Doesn't a wrong or unclear answer deserve to be corrected or clarified? This answer was not clear in that it talks about an object, while the question was about lists (arrays). Future viewers will benefit from any clarification when confusion still exists.

Answer (score 2):

"Is the order of elements in a JSON list maintained?" is not a good question. You need to ask "Is the order of elements in a JSON list maintained when doing [...] ?"
As Felix King pointed out, JSON is a textual data format. It doesn't mutate without a reason. Do not confuse a JSON string with a (JavaScript) object.

You're probably talking about operations like `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(...))`. Now the answer is: It depends on the implementation. 99%* of JSON parsers do not maintain the order of objects, and do maintain the order of arrays, but you might as well use JSON to store something like

```
{
    "son": "David",
    "daughter": "Julia",
    "son": "Tom",
    "daughter": "Clara"
}
```

and use a parser that maintains order of objects.

<sub>*probably even more :)</sub>

Comment: Wrong, at least if you're talking about JSON parser usage. V8 maintains the order, and my guess is that it alone accounts for more than 1% of JSON parser usage. http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=164#c1

Comment: @BenAtkin It's funny that your link points to the explanation on how V8 does **not** maintain the order.

Comment: "The de facto standard is to match
insertion order, which V8 also does, but with one exception"

Comment: @user123444555621 :D
The statement: "_All humans are male, but with one exception: Women are female_" covers all possible cases, but with one exception: humans that cannot be clearly classified as either can be classified eihter as both or as neither.