# Validating dynamically added table row values from external php in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation, dynamically-generated

I am working with a form which consist of dynamic values like adding table rows on button click and I am doing this with jQuery, but now I even want to validate my data before inserting it into my database.

I had to do this validation with external PHP file I am doing this with AJAX, 
but the validation is working well but still the data is being inserted into my database. 
I have tried my best but still its not working for me.

Here is my code:

```
function update_db(){
           var udata = {};
           var adata = {};
           del_query = new Array();
           var confirm = 0;

        var a = "1";   
    if ($("#maintable tbody tr").length>0){

            var vendorid = $("#vendorinfo").val();  

        // prepare data to be updated
           $('[id^="dbtr_"]').each(function(index, table){

               var rid                       = $('th:eq(0)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var basecatid                 = $('td:eq(0)', this).find('select:eq(0)').val();
               var subvendorid               = $('td:eq(0)', this).find('select:eq(0)').val();
               var prodid                    = $('td:eq(1)', this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
               var productname               = $('td:eq(1)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var quantity                  = $('td:eq(2)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var muc                       = $('td:eq(3)', this).find('#muid').val();
               var amt                       = $('td:eq(4)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var reason                    = $('td:eq(5)', this).find('textarea:eq(0)').val();
               var vat_percentage            = $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var total_amount_before_vat   = $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
               var vat_charged_in_bill       = $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(2)').val();
               var invoice                   = $('td:eq(6)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val(); 


               if(invoice =='' && prodid !=''){
                    alert("Invoice Number Cannot Be Empty");
                    $("#savetodb").prop("disabled", true);
                    a = "0";
                    return false;
                 }


            if( quantity !='' && invoice !=''){
             var vouchdt     = $("#dateinfo").val();
                $.ajax({  
                     type: "POST",  
                     url: "../model/check_procurement_resold_with_invoice_number.php", 
                     data: { para : "upd", invno : invoice, product : prodid,  date : vouchdt, quantity : quantity},  
                     success: function(result){
                              if(result == "") {
                                alert(productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+invoice);
                                a = "0";
                                return false
                              }
                             if(result == "2") {
                                alert("Quantity "+ quantity +" for "+productname+" can't be greater than the quantity procured for invoice number "+invoice+" 1");
                                a = "0";
                                return false;
                             }

                     } 
                });
            }

            if (prodid != 'NA' && muc != '' && amt > 0 && rid != '')
            {
                if (quantity>0){
                    udata[rid] = {};
                    udata[rid]['sub_vendor_id'] = subvendorid;
                    udata[rid]['procurement_vendor_id'] = vendorid;
                    udata[rid]['product_id'] = prodid;
                    udata[rid]['quantity'] = quantity;
                    udata[rid]['measurement_unit'] = muc;
                    udata[rid]['amount_received'] = amt;
                    udata[rid]['reason'] = reason;
                    udata[rid]['vat_percentage'] = vat_percentage;
                    udata[rid]['total_amount_before_vat'] = total_amount_before_vat;
                    udata[rid]['vat_charged_in_bill'] = vat_charged_in_bill;
                    udata[rid]['invoice_number'] = invoice;
                }
                else{
                    del_query.push(rid);
                }
            }
        });
     if(a =='1'){
        $.ajax({  
             type: "POST",  
             url: "../model/bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php", 
             data: {action:'updatedb',ud:udata,ad:adata,dd:del_query,username:'<?=$gotuser?>'},  
             success: function(result){
                 results = JSON.parse(result);
                 alert('Number of records Updated : '+results['utotal_s']+"\nNumber Of records Inserted : "+results['acnt']+"\nNumber of records Deleted  : "+results['dcnt']);
            //   window.location.href="bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php?vendorinfo="+vendorid+"&dateinfo="+$("#dateinfo").val()+"&catinfo="+$("#catinfo").val();
             } 
        });
     }
```

here is my php file

```
$proid   = $_POST['product'];
$code    = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["invno"]); 
$vouchdt = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["date"]);
$qty     = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["quantity"]);

$chkqty = mysql_query("SELECT a.quantity_procured, b.invoice_number FROM `gc_procurement_daily_detail` a, `gc_procurement_daily_summary` b 
                        WHERE  a.product_id='".$proid."'
                        AND  b.`date_of_invoice`='".$vouchdt."'
                        AND  b.invoice_number='".$code."'
                        AND  a.`procurement_daily_summary_id`= b.procurement_daily_summary_id")or die(mysql_error());   

if(mysql_num_rows($chkqty) > 0){
   $gqty =0;
   while($row = mysql_fetch_object($chkqty)){
         $mqty = $row->quantity_procured;
         $gqty = $gqty + $mqty;

    }       
    if($qty <= $gqty){
       echo 1;
    }else{
       echo 2;
    }
}else{
    echo '';   
}
```

Comment: Can you include the php of the page(s) you are posting to?

Comment: yes i can but the problem is not from the php file its working fine

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood the problem initially. You are right it's in the ajax, and it's a simple fix. I put the details below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are doing two ajax calls and the second if statement is being hit before the value of a is changed. How the code will be read is:

```
var a = "1";

if ($("#maintable tbody tr").length>0){
   //some code here it goes through in order until:
    $.ajax({ 
          //do this in the background, meanwhile keep executing the code on the page.
       });
}

a is still 1 because results have not come back yet from previous ajax call.    
if(a =='1'){
    $.ajax({  
      //now do this
   });
}
```

What you want to do is nest that second ajax call in the success of the first, e.g.:

```
$.ajax({  
       type: "POST",  
       url: "../model/check_procurement_resold_with_invoice_number.php", 
       data: { para : "upd", invno : invoice, product : prodid,  date : vouchdt, quantity : quantity},  
       success: function(result){

        if(result ==1){
         a = "1";
          $.ajax({  
               type: "POST",  
               url: "../model/bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php", 
               data: {action:'updatedb',ud:udata,ad:adata,dd:del_query,username:'<?=$gotuser?>'},  
               success: function(result){
                   results = JSON.parse(result);
                   alert('Number of records Updated : '+results['utotal_s']+"\nNumber Of records Inserted : "+results['acnt']+"\nNumber of records Deleted  : "+results['dcnt']);
              //   window.location.href="bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php?vendorinfo="+vendorid+"&dateinfo="+$("#dateinfo").val()+"&catinfo="+$("#catinfo").val();
               } 
          });
        } else {
                if(result == "") {
                  alert(productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+invoice);
                  a = "0";
                  return false
                }
               if(result == "2") {
                  alert("Quantity "+ quantity +" for "+productname+" can't be greater than the quantity procured for invoice number "+invoice+" 1");
                  a = "0";
                  return false;
               }
          }
       } 
  });
```

And you'll need to move the `if (prodid != 'NA' && muc != '' && amt > 0 && rid != '')` function above the ajax call as well.

Comment: thanks alot but here there is another problem which i forgot to mention its the ajax is not taking the data in the table row order for  eg : its takin 1st den 4th den 2nd and so on
what could be the problem for that

Comment: That is because it is just an object the way you are sending it. If you want it to maintain it's order, it needs to be an array. More details and discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-maintained