# maintaining order of the ajax request in jquery's $.each()

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic, element

hi  there as per my previous question which got solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19588849/validating-dynamically-added-table-row-values-from-external-php-in-ajax)
i am facing another problem which is that i am using jQuery's $.each() to bind all the dynamically added elements and i want to validate every element as per their order  for eg :-
1st req, 2nd req and then 3rd req  but here the request is not being sent in their order for eg:- 2nd element , 1st eement, 4th element and then 3rd and this keeps on goin i jus want to know how can i keep these request in their order. 
here is my whole jQuery code :-

```
function update_db(){
           var udata = {};
           var adata = {};
           del_query = new Array();
           var confirm = 0;
           var vouchdt     = $("#dateinfo").val();         
           var a = "1";   
    if ($("#maintable tbody tr").length>0){

            var vendorid = $("#vendorinfo").val();  

        // prepare data to be updated
           $('[id^="dbtr_"]').each(function(index, table){

               var rid                       =  $('th:eq(0)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var basecatid                 =  $('td:eq(0)', this).find('select:eq(0)').val();
               var subvendorid               =  $('td:eq(0)', this).find('select:eq(0)').val();
               var prodid                    =  $('td:eq(1)', this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
               var productname               =  $('td:eq(1)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var quantity                  =  $('td:eq(2)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var muc                       =  $('td:eq(3)', this).find('#muid').val();
               var amt                       =  $('td:eq(4)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var reason                    =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('textarea:eq(0)').val();
               var vat_percentage            =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
               var total_amount_before_vat   =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
               var vat_charged_in_bill       =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(2)').val();
               var invoice                   =  $('td:eq(6)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val(); 


               if(invoice =='' && prodid !=''){
                    alert("Invoice Number Cannot Be Empty");
                    $("#savetodb").prop("disabled", true);
                    a = "0";
                    return false;
                 }

        if(prodid !='' && invoice !=''){
        $.ajax({  
             type: "POST",  
             url: "../model/bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php", 
             data: {para :"upd", invno : invoice, product : prodid, date : vouchdt, quantity : qty},  
             success: function(result){
              if(result == "") {
                 alert(productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+id);
                 $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
              }
              if(result == "2") {
                 alert("Quantity "+ qty +" for "+productname+" can't be greater than the quantity procured for invoice number "+id);
                 $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
              }        
              if(result == "3") {
                 alert("Amount "+amt +" For "+productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+id);
                 $("#savetodb").attr("disabled", "disabled");
              }
           } 
        });

        }


            if (prodid != 'NA' && muc != '' && amt > 0 && rid != '')
            {
                if (quantity>0){
                    udata[rid] = {};
                    udata[rid]['sub_vendor_id'] = subvendorid;
                    udata[rid]['procurement_vendor_id'] = vendorid;
                    udata[rid]['product_id'] = prodid;
                    udata[rid]['quantity'] = quantity;
                    udata[rid]['measurement_unit'] = muc;
                    udata[rid]['amount_received'] = amt;
                    udata[rid]['reason'] = reason;
                    udata[rid]['vat_percentage'] = vat_percentage;
                    udata[rid]['total_amount_before_vat'] = total_amount_before_vat;
                    udata[rid]['vat_charged_in_bill'] = vat_charged_in_bill;
                    udata[rid]['invoice_number'] = invoice;
                }
                else{
                    del_query.push(rid);
                }
            }



            if(quantity !='' && invoice !=''){

            }           


        });
        // prepare data to be inserted
        var acount = 0;
        $('[id^="tr_"]').each(function(index, table){
                adata[acount]                = {}; 
                var basecatid                =  $('td:eq(0)', this).find('select:eq(0)').val();
                var subvendorid              =  $('td:eq(0)', this).find('select:eq(0)').val();
                var prodid                   =  $('td:eq(1)', this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
                var quantity                 =  $('td:eq(2)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
                var muc                      =  $('td:eq(3)', this).find('#muid').val();
                var amt                      =  $('td:eq(4)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
                var reason                   =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('textarea:eq(0)').val();
                var vat_percentage           =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();
                var total_amount_before_vat  =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(1)').val();
                var vat_charged_in_bill      =  $('td:eq(5)', this).find('input:eq(2)').val();
                var invoice                  =  $('td:eq(6)', this).find('input:eq(0)').val();



                if(invoice =='' && prodid !=''){
                   alert("Invoice Number Cannot Be Empty");
                   a = "0";
                   console.log(a);
                   return false;
                }

            if( quantity !='' && invoice !=''){

               var vouchdt     = $("#dateinfo").val();
                $.ajax({  
                     type: "POST",  
                     url: "../model/check_procurement_resold_with_invoice_number.php", 
                     data: { para : "upd", invno : invoice, product : prodid,  date : vouchdt, quantity : quantity},  
                     success: function(result){
                         alert(result);
                              if(result == "") {
                                alert(productname+" does not exist for invoice number "+invoice);
                                a = "0";
                                return false
                              }
                             if(result == "2") {
                                alert("Quantity "+ quantity +" for "+productname+" can't be greater than the quantity procured for invoice number "+invoice+" 1");
                                a = "0";
                                return false;
                             }
                     },
                        dataType: 'script',
                        async: false
                });             
            }

                if (prodid != 'NA' && muc != '' && amt != 0 )
                {
                    if (quantity>0){
                        adata[acount]['procurement_vendor_id'] = vendorid;
                        adata[acount]['product_id'] = prodid;
                        adata[acount]['quantity'] = quantity;
                        adata[acount]['measurement_unit'] = muc;
                        adata[acount]['amount_received'] = amt;
                        adata[acount]['reason'] = reason;
                        adata[acount]['date_of_resold'] = $("#dateinfo").val();
                        adata[acount]['vat_percentage'] = vat_percentage;
                        adata[acount]['total_amount_before_vat'] = total_amount_before_vat;
                        adata[acount]['vat_charged_in_bill'] = vat_charged_in_bill;
                        adata[acount]['sub_vendor_id'] = subvendorid;
                        adata[acount]['invoice_number'] = invoice;

                    }
                     acount++;
                 }

        });

     if(a =='1'){
        $.ajax({  
             type: "POST",  
             url: "../model/bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php", 
             data: {action:'updatedb',ud:udata,ad:adata,dd:del_query,username:'<?=$gotuser?>'},  
             success: function(result){
                 results = JSON.parse(result);
                 alert('Number of records Updated : '+results['utotal_s']+"\nNumber Of records Inserted : "+results['acnt']+"\nNumber of records Deleted  : "+results['dcnt']);
                 window.location.href="bulk_procurement_resold_at_lowprice.php?vendorinfo="+vendorid+"&dateinfo="+$("#dateinfo").val()+"&catinfo="+$("#catinfo").val();
             } 
        });
     }

    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: You can use http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/ with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/. A simple example is given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4869609/how-can-jquery-deferred-be-used

Comment: a simple solution (not so good, may block browser) is to use `async:false` in your $.ajax

Comment: @KhanhTO - They should not use `async: false`.  Horrible user experience (locks up the browser).

Comment: You have multiple places you are making ajax requests.  Can you narrow your code down to just the part you need help with, just the part that you're trying to control order with?

Comment: @jfriend00: yes, I mentioned that. That's just a suggestion, in case the OP needs quick fix and his ajax does not take so long.

Comment: hey async : false worked for me

Comment: @user2274075 - please don't use `async: false`.  It locks up the browser during the ajax call and is pretty much NEVER the right way to solve a problem.  It is sometimes the easy way, but not the right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax requests are event driven. Therefore, once a request receives its data, the success: function is called.

You can add the received data to an array as it comes back and then wait until the array is filled ( using if(holderArray.length = x){} or something like that ) with all the returned data to complete your task in order.

Pass the order number along to the success portion in a variable and use that to enter in and then grab the data stored in the array.

```
holderArray[orderNumber] = result;
```