# Keep List<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>> order when converstion to JSONArray

Tags: java, json, list, arrays

I've seen all the posts about keeping order in JSONArray, but I couldn't find a solution.

In this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-maintained), they said : `An array is an ordered collection of values.`

But when I create a `JSONArray` from my `List` I lost the order and I have to keep it.

I've tried all the solutions, but none of them works for me.

I'm using `org.json` as `JSON` lib to create `JSONArray` and then `CDL` to create a `CSV`.

The `List` contains `JSON` so I could create a `CSV` file.

Code :

```
List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> stringObject=new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,Object>>();

for(...; ...;...){
        stringObject.add(map);
    }
/** stringObject is a List containing ordered map */

/** Here I'm trying to create a JSONArray */

JSONARRay jsonArray=new JSONArray(stringObject);
```

Here the ouput :

```
The List : [{_id=1, name=Aurelia Menendez, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=60.06045071030959, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=52.79790691903873, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=71.76133439165544}, {_id=2, name=Corliss Zuk, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=67.03077096065002, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=6.301851677835235, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=66.28344683278382},{.....}]

The JSONArray : [{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":52.79790691903873,"_id":1,"name":"Aurelia Menendez","scores.0.type":"exam","scores.2.type":"homework","scores.0.score":60.06045071030959,"scores.2.score":71.76133439165544},{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":6.301851677835235,"_id":2,"name":"Corlis ...
```

As you can see, I lost the order.

So How to keep the right order so I can create a good `CSV` ?

The `map` order is respected, but the items order inside a `map` is not respected.

**Edits**

Maps I'm adding to the `List` :

```
{_id=1, name=Aurelia Menendez, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=60.06045071030959, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=52.79790691903873, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=71.76133439165544}
{_id=2, name=Corliss Zuk, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=67.03077096065002, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=6.301851677835235, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=66.28344683278382}
{_id=3, name=Bao Ziglar, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=71.64343899778332, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=24.80221293650313, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=42.26147058804812}
{_id=4, name=Zachary Langlais, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=78.68385091304332, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=90.2963101368042, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=34.41620148042529}
{_id=11, name=Marcus Blohm, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=78.42617835651868, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=82.58372817930675, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=87.49924733328717}
{_id=12, name=Quincy Danaher, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=54.29841278520669, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=85.61270164694737, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=80.40732356118075}
{_id=15, name=Tambra Mercure, scores.0.type=exam, scores.0.score=69.1565022533158, scores.1.type=quiz, scores.1.score=3.311794422000724, scores.2.type=homework, scores.2.score=45.03178973642521}
```

Using JSONObject :

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
for(LinkedHashMap<String,Object> map:stringObject){

    jsonObject.putAll(map);
    System.out.println(jsonObject);
}
```

Output :

```
{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":52.79790691903873,"_id":1,"name":"Aurelia Menendez","scores.0.type":"exam","scores.2.type":"homework","scores.0.score":60.06045071030959,"scores.2.score":71.76133439165544}
{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":6.301851677835235,"_id":2,"name":"Corliss Zuk","scores.0.type":"exam","scores.2.type":"homework","scores.0.score":67.03077096065002,"scores.2.score":66.28344683278382}
{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":24.80221293650313,"_id":3,"name":"Bao Ziglar","scores.0.type":"exam","scores.2.type":"homework","scores.0.score":71.64343899778332,"scores.2.score":42.26147058804812}
{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":90.2963101368042,"_id":4,"name":"Zachary Langlais","scores.0.type":"exam","scores.2.type":"homework","scores.0.score":78.68385091304332,"scores.2.score":34.41620148042529}
{"scores.1.type":"quiz","scores.1.score":82.58372817930675,"_id":11,"name":"Marcus Blohm","scores.0.type":"exam","scores.2.type":"homework","scores.0.score":78.42617835651868,"scores.2.score":87.49924733328717}
```

Ismail

Comment: The array is keeping the order. But for some reason you have only one thing in the array, and that thing is an object (which does not preserve order) which has your actual data in it.

Comment: @immibis, in the loop I add a `LinkedHashMap` at every iteration. So my list contains several maps. Do you mean that I couldn't have the order when I do the JSONArray ?

Comment: I didn't see the `,{...}` at the end of the output, so now I realize you do have multiple maps. What I said still mostly applies - arrays keep order, but objects (maps) don't. And the array retained the order of the objects, and the objects didn't retain the order of their properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking at the wrong place. The elements of the list stay in order (`List` and `JSONArray` keep the order).

But you add maps to the `JSONArray`. The conversion of the **items** in each individual map seems to lose the ordering. You can check that by converting just a single map to `JSONObject`.

To answer how to preserve this order, I need to know which JSON framework you're using.

**EDIT** You're using the default json.org Java framework. As the documentation clearly states:

> A JSONObject is an unordered collection of name/value pairs.

So there is no way to do it with this framework.

I checked jackson but couldn't find any indication that it preserves the sort order of map elements.

My guess is that this is because JavaScript doesn't support this.

Comment: I've mentionned that I'm using `org.json` . Also, I've tried `JSONObject` but it didn't work too. I've added in the **Edits** the output when I use `JSONObject`

Comment: It's clear now that the problem came from `items` inside a `map`. The reason I wanna keep them ordered is to create the right `CSV`. Is it possible to keep the items order ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible with JSON. What you can try is to look into the serialization code of your JSON framework and manually serialize the maps, entry by entry.

Answer (score 3):

Lets look at the below code of yours and understand whats is exactly happening.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
 for(LinkedHashMap<String,Object> map:stringObject){

jsonObject.putAll(map);
System.out.println(jsonObject);
}
```

So lets examine whats happening here.... 
when you call jsonObject.putAll(map).....this is what happens

```
public JSONObject putAll(Map<String, Object> newProperties)
{
    assert newProperties != null;

    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> e : newProperties.entrySet())
    {
        this.put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }

    return this;
}
```

This method is iterating over map(in your case Ordered map i.e. LinkedHashMap) one by one and adding it to its own put method with key and value as arguments.

Now let see what happens in put method

```
public JSONObject put(String key, Object value) throws JSONException {
    if (key == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("Null key.");
    }
    if (value != null) {
        testValidity(value);
        this.map.put(key, value);
    } else {
        this.remove(key);
    }
    return this;
}
```

Here it simply puts that key value in its own map which is basically a hashmap in the end.
As you know that hash map is not ordered . So thats why when you look at the output of it it is basically not in the order you have inserted.

Comment: Changed the loop but did'nt work, same output. The order is not respected, plus I've have a warning  : `Type safety: The method putAll(Map) belongs to the raw type HashMap. References to generic type HashMap<K,V> should be parameterized`when I do : `jsonObject.putAll(stringObject.get(i)`. (I can't use `put`)

Comment: If you try with a `map` as I gave in the edits you will notice that it wont work.

Comment: @AaronDigulla thanks man. I did google it and found that i was wrong. Foreach iterates in order.

Comment: @ParasMittal I guess you are right. Eventually its gonna be Hashmap so there's no point taking LinkedHashMap as in the end jsonObject will add entry to its Hashmap which does not keeps its order.

Answer (score 1):

From your question i think you are not getting the order of insertion same as order of output.
I just double checked it and found that you are wrong. I have done the following thing and getting the following output.

```
/*******************output*************/



[{"val0":"val0"},{"val1":"val1"},{"val2":"val2"},{"val3":"val3"},{"val4":"val4"},{"val5":"val5"},{"val6":"val6"},{"val7":"val7"},{"val8":"val8"},{"val9":"val9"}]

/********************************/

 /************** Code****************/

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;

public class TestOrderArrayList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>> stringObject = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, Object>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        LinkedHashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
        hashMap.put("val" + i, "val" + i);
        stringObject.add(hashMap);
    }
    /** stringObject is a List containing ordered map */

    /** Here I'm trying to create a JSONArray */

    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(stringObject);

    System.out.println(jsonArray);
}
}
```

If there's something else you want to say. please elaborate a little bit.

Hope this solves your query.

Comment: This what I'm doing too, I add a `map` at every iteration. I tried your example and I got the same result as yours. But my example doesn't work, I lost the order once I call `JSONArray`

Comment: Could you attach your example. May b there's a minute detail you are missing.

Comment: Could please see the **Edits**. I've added the `maps` I use.

Comment: OPs maps have several items in them. The order of maps is correct but the order of items in the maps is randomized. My guess is that `JSONObject` doesn't preserve order.

Comment: @AtulSharma If you try with a `map` as I gave in the edits you will notice that it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

According the values you specified in the "Output" section, the JsonArray in the JsonObject is retaining the order [same order maintained in the List Object].

You do not have to worry about the order of JSonElements in your response, as according to the JSON specification they need not be maintained.

For example:
`JsonString1 = {"id":2,"name":"John"} 
 JsonString2 = {"name":"John","id":2}` are exactly the same. i.e if you use org.json classes or Jackson to check equality of the above JsonObjects they will be equal.

On the flipside if you want the same order in your JsonArrays every time you run your program, I suppose you should be using a LinkedList<> instead of a List<>.