# JSON response how to change object position

Tags: java, json

I am generating below response using java code ( java response Object), I would like to format response , tried changing sequence of object

Expected output

```
{
"header": {
      "specVersion": "1.0",
      "correlationId": "2526a923-6953-4dbc-a000-778f22de339c",
      "payloadContentType": "application/json",
      "id": "241f6d36-b792-4b61-9526-9d3b6270cc3c",
      "time": "2022-08-02 11:01:51.439",
      "applicationInstanceId": "v1"
   },
   "payload": {
      "success": {
         "code": 200,
         "message": "OK",
             },
      "failure": {
         "code": 0
      },
      "fileUid": "324343-b792-4b61-9526-9d3b6270cc3c"
   },
   "fileID": "241f6d36-b792-4b61-9526-9d3b6270cc3c"
}
```

Current output

```
{
   "payload": {Sucess and failure block
                },
   "header": { header block
   },
   "fileID": "id"
}
```

Comment: You want JSON to be in a particular order?   You can't have it - JSON objects are by definition unordered.  And code that expects a particular order is broken code.

Comment: There are plenty of existing answers saying the same thing. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697119/java-json-object-insertion-order-maintenance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java JSON object insertion order maintenance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697119/java-json-object-insertion-order-maintenance)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What library do you need to serialize Java object to JSON string? If using Jackson, you can use `@JsonPropertyOrder` or `@JsonProperty` with parameter `index`(like `@JsonProperty(index = 1)`) to custom orders of fields.

Using `@JsonPropertyOrder`

```
// string array will control the order of fields
@JsonPropertyOrder({"payload", "header", "fileID"})
public class Response {
  private HeaderClass header;
  private PayloadClass payload;
  private String fileID;
}
```

Using `@JsonProperty`

```
public class Response {
  // index will control the order of field
  @JsonProperty(index = 2)
  private HeaderClass header;
  @JsonProperty(index = 1)
  private PayloadClass payload;
  @JsonProperty(index = 3)
  private String fileID;
}
```