# python json dump, how to make specify key first?

Tags: python, json

I want to dump this json to a file:

```
json.dumps(data)
```

This is the data:

```
 {
       "list":[
        "one": { "id": "12","desc":"its 12","name":"pop"},
        "two": {"id": "13","desc":"its 13","name":"kindle"}
        ]
    }
```

I want `id` to be the first property after I dump it to file, but it is not. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show us your code for dumping this JSON into a file

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that it's because you're using a dictionary (hash-map). It's unsortable.
What you could do is:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
data = OrderedDict()
data['list'] = OrderedDict()
data['list']['one'] = OrderedDict()
data['list']['one']['id'] = '12'
data['list']['one']['idesc'] = ...
data['list']['two'] = ...
```

This makes it sorted by order of input.
It's "impossible" to know the output of a dict/hashmap because the nature (and speed) of a traditional dictionary makes the sort/access order vary depending on usage, items in the dictionary and a lot of other factors.
So you need to either pass your dictionary to a `sort()` function prior to sending it to json or use a slower version of the dictionary called `OrderedDict` (see above).

Many thanks goes out to @MarcoNawijn for checking the source of JSON that **does not honor the sort structure of the dictionary**, which means you'll have to build the JSON string yourself.

If the parser on the other end of your JSON string honors the order (which i doubt), you could pass this to a function that builds a regular text-string representation of your `OrderedDict` and formatting the string as per JSON standards. This will however take up more time than I have at this moment since i'm not 100% certain of the RFC for JSON strings.

Comment: This does not work. `json.dump(..)` does not respect the order in which key/value pairs are added. You can easily check this in the interactive interpreter. The `json.dump(..)` function does have a `sort_keys` attribute, but you cannot provide a custom sort function (as far as I can tell without looking at the actual implementation of it). If the actual location of the `id` attribute is important, I would suggest to use the `sort_keys` attribute. The `id` attribute will than at least be at a consistent/predictable location.

Comment: So, I checked the implementation of `json.dump(..)`. It indeed hardcodes the sort function to sort on the key: `sorted(dct.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[0])`.

Comment: @MarcoNawijn Thank you for clairifying this. I didn't think json hardcoded the sort order. Considering the fact that JSON is defined to not be of a specific order on the output end of things, I don't see why this is a relevant question even tho the problem that the user is faced intrigues me :)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldnt worry about the order in which json is saved. The order will be changed when dumping. Better look at these too. [JSON order mixed up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948206/json-order-mixed-up)
and
[Is the order of elements in a JSON list maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-maintained)