# Modify JSON-File and save it back as a file in exactly the same order with Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a json-file that I want to read, and then modify the value of a specific key, and then save it in exactly the same order..

I achieved the modification successfully, but in the JSONArray, now when writing it as JSON-File (JSONString), I get 2 problems:

1) The order of the parameters (keys) change

2) The german-letters get encoded to weird characters..

So how can I do the modification with saving the changes in exactly the same order they were read, and letting the german-characters as they are?

Here is the structure of my json-file:

```
[{
    "key1": "key here",
    "key2": "key2 here",
    "key3": "pId here11",
    "details": {
        "detailsKey1": "https://linkHere.com/conf/conf1/conf2/img/testImage.png",
        "detailsKey2": "desc here",
        "detailsKey3": "some url here",
        "detailsKeys4": "some key here",
        "terms": [{
            "termsKey1": "über dreißig",
            "termsKey2": "mäßig term here"
        }]
    }
}, {
    "key1": "key here",
    "key2": "key2 here",
    "key3": "pId here11",
    "details": {
        "detailsKey1": "https://linkHere.com/conf/conf1/conf2/img/testImage.png",
        "detailsKey2": "desc here",
        "detailsKey3": "some url here",
        "detailsKeys4": "some key here",
        "terms": [{
            "termsKey1": "über dreißig",
            "termsKey2": "mäßig term here"
        }]
    }
}]
```

I want to modify just the detailsKey1's value! I want to change that link for every object in my file, with a new string.

Here is my code:

```
public class testi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JSONException, IOException, NoSuchFieldException, SecurityException, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {

    String jsonOldData = readFile("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\img.json");
    JSONArray jOldArray =  new JSONArray(jsonOldData);

    ArrayList<String> myOldArray = new ArrayList<>();

    System.out.println("length old: " + jOldArray.length());

    for(int i=0; i < jOldArray.length(); i++) {
        System.out.println("link here" + i + ": " + jOldArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("details").getString("detailsKey1"));
        if (i == 0) {
            jOldArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("details").put("detailsKey1", "testImage.png");
            System.out.println("NEW teaserImage " + i + ": " + jOldArray.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("details").getString("detailsKey1"));
        }
        if (i==2)
            System.out.println("teaserImage " + (i-2) + ": " + jOldArray.getJSONObject(i-2).getJSONObject("details").getString("detailsKey1"));
    }
}

public static String readFile(String filename) {

    String result = "";
    try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
    }

}
```

As you can see/test, the change take place in the Array, but I dont know how to go further now, to get my new (updated) file saved in my Desktop, with the same keys oder.

Comment: is your `keys` and `detailedkeys` are fixed in numbers (i mean 1 to 4 only). If it is so then only i can provide a solution to it

Comment: one more suggestion to you. please use `switch` rather than `if`. Switch will reduce your complexity  . Thankx

Comment: Please post your readFile method. I suspect your issue with German chars is due to encoding. You should be using a Reader with the right Chartset. Or, if this is Jackson, you should just pass an InputStream and let Jackson decode it - see http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonBestPracticesPerformance#A3._Use_the_.22least_processed.22_forms_of_input_source

Comment: no.. that was just an example to show you how the structure of the json is, and how it should be kept..

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects are unordered sets of name/value pairs according to the [JSON Spec](http://www.json.org/); so I would question the need for this feature firstly.

In addition, while the [JsonArray](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html) library in java is written to this spec you can get the index of items in the JSON, but [JsonWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonWriter.html) will not let you specify an index to insert into the JSON.

If order is a necessity, I would suggest writing your own parser that does not conform to the JSON spec, then again the effort required seems to outweigh any potential benefit.

Answer (score 0):

Json will not maintain the ordering of the objects in the data... it is in it's specification.... please go through this link about more information... [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214312/4626402)

And about the encoding issue try using google's json library known as gson.... The below code work's fine in printing the data as is...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
    a.put("über dreißig", "mäßig term here");
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(a));
}
```

the maven dependencies for gson is as follows::

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't think this is a solution to for this question.