# Use Python for Creating JSON

Tags: python, configuration, introspection, python-attrs

I want to use Python for creating JSON.

Since I found no library which can help me, I want to know if it's possible to inspect the order of the classes in a Python file?

Example

```
# example.py
class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass
```

If I import `example`, I want to know the order of the classes. In this case it is [Foo, Bar] and not [Bar, Foo].

Is this possible? If "yes", how?

## Background

I am not happy with yaml/json. I have the vague idea to create config via Python classes (only classes, not instantiation to objects).

Answers which help me to get to my goal (Create JSON with a tool which is easy and fun to use) are welcome.

Comment: That's a great vague idea.  You should give [Figura](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a shot!

Comment: I should point out the order of declarations is not preserved in Figura, and [also not in json](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7214312), and also not in YAML.

Comment: @shx2 AFAIK the order in yaml gets preserved. Otherwise ordering states in saltstack would not work: https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/ordering.html

Comment: @shx2 I looked at the tutorial of Figura. It's hard to read the examples, since my eyes mostly see `"""`. Are the comments needed?

Comment: ok, I'll consider making it easier on the eye ;)  However, you don't really need to the docs. Getting started is really easy. See the hello_world.py

Comment: Try: `from figura import read_config; read_config('figura.hello_world')`

Comment: Do you want merely the order of class declaration or do you want some attributes set as well?

Comment: Going back to your original, original question -- have you tried the `json` library? What did you find lacking? It's standard, simple and very usable.

Comment: @ChrisJohnson Using the json library is coding. I would like to prefer "defining". I know my sentence is vague. I would like to use inheritance an mixins like LEGO bricks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The inspect module can tell the line numbers of the class declarations:

```
import inspect

def get_classes(module):
    for name, value in inspect.getmembers(module):
        if inspect.isclass(value):
            _, line = inspect.getsourcelines(value)
            yield line, name
```

So the following code:

```
import example

for line, name in sorted(get_classes(example)):
    print line, name
```

Prints:

```
2 Foo
5 Bar
```

Comment: This requires the example module to be on the import path and also is a pretty big security hole, you're loading a user-editable file in the same context as the rest of the application, without any sort of sandbox...

Comment: @pradyunsg: he wrote that "If I import example" so importing doesn't seem to a problem.

Comment: Oh... Still, I see that as a bit of a security hole. Added a section to my answer.

Comment: Yes, can be, depending on the use case.

Comment: Of course, depending on the use-case. If it's not accessible to a random person on earth, it's probably fine.

Comment: This can be useful in many cases, but isn't a general solution for all modules -- the `getsourcelines` method won't be available when the module is not pure Python, i.e. if it is a C extension.

Comment: You were the first to answer this question. I changed the question (I guess this was no good idea). You get the bounty! Thank you for answering my question! The other answers are good, too. I see no clear winner.

Comment: Thank you! Though I'm prefering the `ast` based solution which I've learned from @pradyunsg's answer.

Answer (score 3):

First up, as I see it, there are 2 things you can do...

1. Continue pursuing to use Python source files as configuration files. (I won't recommend this. It's analogous to using a bulldozer to strike a nail or converting [a shotgun](http://bjorn.tipling.com/if-programming-languages-were-weapons) to a wheel)
2. Switch to something like [TOML](https://github.com/toml-lang/toml), [JSON](http://json.org/) or [YAML](http://yaml.org/) for configuration files, which are designed for the job.

   Nothing in JSON or YAML prevents them from holding "ordered" key-value pairs. Python's `dict` data type is unordered by default (at least till 3.5) and `list` data type is ordered. These map directly to object and array in JSON respectively, when using the default loaders. Just use something like Python's `OrderedDict` when deserializing them and voila, you preserve order!

---

With that out of the way, if you *really* want to use Python source files for the configuration, I suggest trying to process the file using the `ast` module. Abstract Syntax Trees are a powerful tool for syntax level analysis.

I whipped a quick script for extracting class line numbers and names from a file.

You (or anyone really) can use it or extend it to be more extensive and have more checks if you want for whatever you want.

```
import sys
import ast
import json


class ClassNodeVisitor(ast.NodeVisitor):

    def __init__(self):
        super(ClassNodeVisitor, self).__init__()
        self.class_defs = []

    def visit(self, node):
        super(ClassNodeVisitor, self).visit(node)
        return self.class_defs

    def visit_ClassDef(self, node):
        self.class_defs.append(node)


def read_file(fpath):
    with open(fpath) as f:
        return f.read()


def get_classes_from_text(text):
    try:
        tree = ast.parse(text)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

    class_extractor = ClassNodeVisitor()

    li = []
    for definition in class_extractor.visit(tree):
        li.append([definition.lineno, definition.name])

    return li


def main():
    fpath = "/tmp/input_file.py"

    try:
        text = read_file(fpath)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Could not load file due to " + repr(e))
        return 1

    print(json.dumps(get_classes_from_text(text), indent=4))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

Here's a sample run on the following file:

`input_file.py`:

```
class Foo:
    pass


class Bar:
    pass
```

Output:

```
$ py_to_json.py input_file.py
[
    [
        1,
        "Foo"
    ],
    [
        5,
        "Bar"
    ]
]
```

---

> If I import `example`,

If you're going to import the module, the `example` module to be on the import path. Importing means executing *any* Python code in the `example` module. This is a pretty big security hole - you're loading a user-editable file in the same context as the rest of the application.

Comment: The `ast` module is pretty nice, thanks for the example. I've played with it until I've reached a one-liner: `[(n.lineno, n.name) for n in ast.walk(ast.parse(open("example.py").read())) if isinstance(n, ast.ClassDef)]`

Comment: Yes. That works too. I feel silly. My best possible comeback is: I did so much since I'm not sure if OP wants just the class name or also the assignments inside it. (Because I wrote code for that too, then removed it)

Comment: Both the `ast.NodeVisitor` and `ast.walk` walk the tree. The `ast.walk` is simpler for this one-liner, but `ast.NodeVisitor` can be more elegant for more complex processing. I just prefer shorter examples because it's easier for the readers to understand.

Comment: Agreed. But shorter examples are not *always* easier, but more often than not.

Comment: @NorbertSebők You can use `"".join(inspect.getsourcelines(example)[0])` instead of `open("example.py").read()` if you imported `example.py`

Comment: Yes @plean, that is an other way. I've shown an `inspect` example in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

*(Moving my comments to an answer)*

That's a great vague idea. You should **give [Figura](https://figura.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a shot!**  It does exactly that.

*(Full disclosure: I'm the author of Figura.)*

I should point out the order of declarations is not preserved in Figura, and also not in json.

I'm not sure about order-preservation in YAML, but I did find this on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML#Data_processing_and_representation):

> ... according to the specification, mapping keys do not have an order

It might be the case that specific YAML parsers maintain the order, though they aren't required to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that since you care about preserving **class-definition order**, you also care about preserving the **order of definitions within each class**.

It is worth pointing out that is now **the default behavior in python**, [since python3.6](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep520).

Aslo see *[PEP 520](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0520): Preserving Class Attribute Definition Order*.

Comment: That's great news. Up to now we still use Python 2.7, but sooner or later we will switch. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a metaclass to record each class's creation time, and later, sort the classes by it.

This works in python2:

```
class CreationTimeMetaClass(type): 
    creation_index = 0
    def __new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct):
        dct['__creation_index__'] = cls.creation_index
        cls.creation_index += 1
        return type.__new__(cls, clsname, bases, dct)

__metaclass__ = CreationTimeMetaClass

class Foo: pass
class Bar: pass

classes = [ cls for cls in globals().values() if hasattr(cls, '__creation_index__') ]
print(sorted(classes, key = lambda cls: cls.__creation_index__))
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module is easy to use and works well for reading and writing JSON config files.

Objects are not ordered within JSON structures but lists/arrays are, so put order dependent information into a list.

I have used classes as a configuration tool, the thing I did was to derive them from a base class which was customised by the particular class variables. By using the class like this I did not need a factory class. For example:

```
from .artifact import Application
class TempLogger(Application): partno='03459'; path='c:/apps/templog.exe'; flag=True
class GUIDisplay(Application): partno='03821'; path='c:/apps/displayer.exe'; flag=False
```

in the installation script

```
from .install import Installer
import app_configs

installer = Installer(apps=(TempLogger(), GUIDisplay()))
installer.baseline('1.4.3.3475')
print installer.versions()
print installer.bill_of_materials()
```

One should use the right tools for the job, so perhaps python classes are not the right tool if you need ordering.

Another python tool I have used to create JSON files is [Mako](http://www.makotemplates.org/) templating system. This is very powerful. We used it to populate variables like IP addresses etc into static JSON files that were then read by C++ programs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is answers your question, but it might be relevant. Take a look at the excellent [attrs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/attrs) module. It's great for creating classes to use as data types.

Here's an example from [glyph's](https://glyph.twistedmatrix.com/2016/08/attrs.html) blog (creator of Twisted Python):

```
import attr
@attr.s
class Point3D(object):
    x = attr.ib()
    y = attr.ib()
    z = attr.ib()
```

It saves you writing a lot of boilerplate code - you get things like `str` representation and comparison for free, and the module has a convenient `asdict` function which you can pass to the `json` library:

```
>>> p = Point3D(1, 2, 3)
>>> str(p)
'Point3D(x=1, y=2, z=3)'
>>> p == Point3D(1, 2, 3)
True
>>> json.dumps(attr.asdict(p))
'{"y": 2, "x": 1, "z": 3}'
```

The module uses a strange naming convention, but read `attr.s` as "attrs" and `attr.ib` as "attrib" and you'll be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Just touching the point about creating JSON from python. there is an excellent library called [jsonpickle](https://jsonpickle.github.io/) which lets you dump python objects to json. (and using this alone or with other methods mentioned here you can probably get what you wanted)

Comment: does it work for classes, too? I don't have objects.

Comment: it can work for classes but it really depends what are your needs. from what i saw it will encode to something like: "py/object": "<module name>.B" and later it can decode it to reconstruct B it module is accesible