# How to find out which place in an object a given property is in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object

For example, if I have an object like:

```
{"angeredoutsidecontrol":"1","difficultiespileup":"2"}
```

And then later in a for loop I can access the key of **angeredoutsidecontrol** , how can I get the value returned as 0, which would represent which place in the object this key is?

Comment: Don't depend on the order of keys in an object. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I doubt keys have any guaranteed ordering in the spec, but you can do `Object.keys(yourObject).indexOf("angeredoutsidecontrol")`. I'd recommend rethinking what you're doing though.

Comment: there is no  guarantee on order of keys in es

Comment: Iterating over an object is decidedly random. There's no ordering. The best you can do is to dump them into an array and grab that index.

Comment: If order is important, use an array.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I remembered people saying that the order of keys can't be guaranteed, now it's confirmed.

Comment: @AnthonyMayfield What are you actually trying to do? Maybe we can help sort that issue out.

Comment: @Gavin, it's fine, I'm just going to go about things a different way, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guaranteed order for keys of an object.

Definition of object from an old - but still effective in this case - [documentation](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf):

> 4.3.3 Object
>
> An object is a member of the type Object. It is an unordered
>   collection of properties each of which contains a primitive value,
>   object, or function. A function stored in a property of an object is
>   called a method.

If order really matters to you, use array instead. For example:

```
[{ "angeredoutsidecontrol": "1" }
 { "difficultiespileup": "2" }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of JSON objects is not maintained, so you can't do this.

[[Is the order of elements in a JSON list maintained?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-maintained][1])

Comment: These two terms are used interchangeably in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
var myMoods = ["angeredoutsidecontrol","difficultiespileup"];
```

and

```
myMoods.indexOf( 'angeredoutsidecontrol' )
```

gives you position in your list