# REST api returned json gets sorted in increasing order automatically

Tags: rest, go

I am working on REST api build with golang when I am returning a json of employees like

```
{
   "data":{
      "10":{
         "1517616000":[1000]
      },
      "15":{
         "1517616000":[1200]
      },
      "29":{
         "1517616000":[1200]
      },
      "42":{
         "1517616000":[1200]
      }
   }
}
```

it should be showing in 42,15,29,10 order as I am sorting the data with priority parameter. When I check with console it shows me correct output but not on postman and browser

Used following function to return json

```
c.JSON(200, gin.H{
  "status": response,
 })
```

Comment: Json objects are un-ordered. Perhaps you should use an array instead. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214312/9143962

Comment: its application/json

Comment: Really... 3 downvotes without any reason, people seems to be reviewing the question based on if they like it or not but not on technical aspects I guess. Anyways ... happens sometimes

Comment: And really, I think technical aspects have been stated in my comments. Though I did not downvote you.

Comment: @leafbebop That what should be appreciated , however I got ideas from your comment. sometimes a single hint leads to solution.

Comment: Then I think it is encouraged to answer your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you store the 42,15,29,10 as keys in a Go `map`, the JSON [`mapEncoder`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/ed6c6c9c11496ed8e458f6e0731103126ce60223/src/encoding/json/encode.go#L658-L685) is going to sort them by key when printing to JSON.

Instead we can store the data as elements in a slice, which preserves the order we specify. In order to have the slice print as a JSON map rather than a JSON array we need to plug in a bit of our own JSON marshaling logic.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Response struct {
    Data OrderedMap `json:"data"`
}

type OrderedMap []Entry

type Entry struct {
    Key   string
    Value interface{}
}

func (m OrderedMap) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    var buf bytes.Buffer
    buf.WriteByte('{')
    for i, entry := range m {
        if i != 0 {
            buf.WriteByte(',')
        }
        key, err := json.Marshal(entry.Key)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        buf.Write(key)
        buf.WriteByte(':')
        value, err := json.Marshal(entry.Value)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        buf.Write(value)
    }
    buf.WriteByte('}')
    return buf.Bytes(), nil
}

func main() {
    response := Response{
        Data: OrderedMap{
            {"42", map[string][]int{"1517616000": []int{1200}}},
            {"15", map[string][]int{"1517616000": []int{1200}}},
            {"29", map[string][]int{"1517616000": []int{1200}}},
            {"10", map[string][]int{"1517616000": []int{1000}}},
        },
    }

    j, err := json.MarshalIndent(response, "", "  ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(j))
}
```

The result is the same JSON representation you were seeing before but with the keys in the order specified by our `OrderedMap`.

```
{
  "data": {
    "42": {
      "1517616000": [1200]
    },
    "15": {
      "1517616000": [1200]
    },
    "29": {
      "1517616000": [1200]
    },
    "10": {
      "1517616000": [1000]
    }
  }
}
```