# Using List for JSON Array

Tags: json, list, insertion-order

Updating based on further exploring and thanks to @pinaka30 for the comment-

I wanted to verify if I deserialize JSON array into List, will that preserve the sequence.

I took the below JSON

```
{
  "MyJSON": {
    "name": "Any Name",
    "values": [
        "1111",
        "2222",
        "3333",
        "4444",
        "5555",
        "6666"
    ]
  }
}
```

The DTO that I created is as follows:

```
package com.jsonrelated.jsonrelated;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "MyJSONMapping"
})
public class MyJSONMapping {

    @JsonProperty("MyJSON")
    @Valid
    @NotNull
    private MyJSON myJSON;

    @JsonProperty("MyJSON")
    public MyJSON getMyJSON() {
        return myJSON;
    }

    @JsonProperty("MyJSON")
    public void setMyJSON(MyJSON myJSON) {
        this.myJSON = myJSON;
    }
}

package com.jsonrelated.jsonrelated;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

import java.util.List;


@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "name",
        "values"
})
public class MyJSON {

    @JsonProperty("name")
    String name;

    @JsonProperty("values")
    List<String> values;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(List<String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }
}
```

Then I have created a REST API and sending that JSON as request Body

```
    @RequestMapping(path="generateMyJSONChart",method=RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json",consumes="application/json")
    public String generateMyJSONChart(@Valid @RequestBody MyJSONMapping myJSONMapping, @RequestParam("type") @NotBlank String type) throws IOException {

        List comparedProducts = myJSONMapping.getMyJSON().getValues();

        Iterator i = comparedProducts.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext())
        {
            String name = (String) i.next();
            System.out.println(name);
        }

        return "nothing";
    }
```

I was checking if the sequence of the values in "Values" as in

```
    "values": [
        "1111",
        "2222",
        "3333",
        "4444",
        "5555",
        "6666"
    ]
```

are preserved if we deserialize them into List as in

```
    @JsonProperty("values")
    List<String> values;
```

I have run it multiple times with 100 elements in the values and I see the order is preserved.

Adding a good post already there [Is the order of elements in a JSON list preserved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7214293/is-the-order-of-elements-in-a-json-list-preserved) so mine seems to be duplicate.

Comment: Why would it not be preserved? The list is filled in order of JSON list only. So the element which was inserted first in JSON would be inserted first in list as well.

Comment: Thanks you @PiNaKa30