# With jq how to get the name of the parent element that contains "DOWN"?

Tags: jq

```json
{
      "status": "DOWN",
      "components": {
          "ping": {
              "status": "UP",
              "details": {
                  "version": "1.0.0",
                  "description": "dobre application",
                  "name": "SO-3113"
              }
          },
          "bridge.lock": {
              "status": "UP",
              "details": {
                  "description": "test1"
              }
          },
          "Configuration converted": {
              "status": "DOWN",
              "details": {
                  "description": "test2"
              }
          },
          "app started": {
              "status": "DOWN",
              "details": {
                  "description": "test3"
              }
          }
      }
  }
```

I need to get the name of first component with DOWN status ("Configuration converted" in above json). So far i managed to get only `.details.description` of it:

```sh
jq -c '.components| .[] | select( .status | contains("DOWN")) .details.description' | head -1
```

How can I get the name (key) of component? ("Configuration converted")

Comment: I don´t get clear your question, I executed your query with your json in https://jqplay.org/ and it returned to me: "test2" "test3". Could you said me what is your desired output please?

Comment: need "Configuration converted" because this is first contains "DOWN". Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `to_entries` function to convert the objects within `.components` into key/value pairs and provide an expression that selects the first object matching the condition and retrieve its key

```
.components | 
to_entries  | 
map(select(.value.status == "DOWN"))[0].key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `to_entries` to get the key/values of your components , then select the first one with down status:

```
first(.components | to_entries | .[] | select( .value.status == "DOWN") | .key)
```

[Run it on jqplay](https://jqplay.org/s/f-hCdZ4_vI)

Comment: also note that the order of object keys do not have a real meaning, if you want to preserve order ,you should use arrays instead of object : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214316/4718434

Comment: It would be better to avoid `contains/1`, which has complex semantics at best, and does not seem to match the requirements here.  A check using `==` should suffice.

Comment: @peak Agree, Updated the answer.