# Can I sort order of fields within jsonb_agg / jsonb_build_object?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Through much trial & error, I've been able to expand an existing SQL query to return the comments associated with each media file in my app.  Here's an example of the enhanced query:

```
SELECT m.media_id, m.name, m.path, m.original_name, m.description, m.privacy, m.size, m.type, m.file_type, m.file_size, 
       m.width, m.height, m.date_created, m.date_uploaded, m.media_set_id, r.rating,
       jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('comment', c.comment, 'parent_id', c.parent_id, 'user_id', c.user_id, 'date_updated', c.date_updated)) filter (where c.comment is not null and c.date_deleted is null) as comments,
       array_agg(t.tag) filter (where t.tag is not null) as tags 
FROM media m JOIN users u USING (user_id) 
LEFT JOIN media_tags mt USING (media_id) 
LEFT JOIN tags t USING (tag_id) 
LEFT JOIN ratings r using (media_id, user_id) 
LEFT JOIN comments c using (media_id)
WHERE u.user_id = 'b14c1548-d433-4bc2-9059-9091262e7305' AND m.date_deleted IS NULL AND m.privacy != 'support' 
GROUP BY m.media_id, m.name, m.path, m.original_name, m.description, m.privacy, m.size, m.type, m.file_type, m.file_size, 
         m.width, m.height, m.date_created, m.date_uploaded, m.media_set_id, r.rating 
ORDER BY date(m.date_created) DESC, m.date_created ASC, m.date_uploaded ASC
```

The critical part is this:

```
jsonb_agg(distinct jsonb_build_object('comment', c.comment, 'parent_id', c.parent_id, 'user_id', c.user_id, 'date_updated', c.date_updated)) filter (where c.comment is not null and c.date_deleted is null) as comments,
```

Here's an example of one set of `comments` that contains 3 user comments:

```
[{"comment": "Comment 1 (Jay)", "user_id": "e8e4144d-f610-4c7f-a6a6-77355e16c297", "parent_id": null, "date_updated": "2024-02-16T11:30:09.406089-06:00"}, {"comment": "Comment 1 (Rob)", "user_id": "b14c1548-d433-4bc2-9059-9091262e7305", "parent_id": null, "date_updated": "2024-02-16T11:27:33.465173-06:00"}, {"comment": "Comment 2 (Rob)", "user_id": "b14c1548-d433-4bc2-9059-9091262e7305", "parent_id": null, "date_updated": "2024-02-16T11:31:25.197722-06:00"}]
```

The one last thing I'd like to do is sort each set of comments in increasing order of `date_updated` but can't figure out how to do that.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: jsonb is not sorted and there is no guarantee that input A,B will be A,B forever. B,A is just as good. When your application relies on some ordering, you'd better but a row number in the json content and let the application handle the ordering when processing the content.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I think OP means the oreder of the JSON array objects, which definitely has guaranteed ordering. You can use `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY` for this.

Comment: In Postgres you put the `ORDER BY` inside the aggregate for non-ordered-set aggregates https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES

Comment: @Charlieface You can order an array, but as soon as it becomes a JSONB array, there won't be a guarantee that the order is stable. And please link to the "current" documentation, not an outdated unsupported version.

Comment: @FrankHeikens I'm pretty sure that's only true of object keys, not arrays. See https://dbfiddle.uk/VqGThSJP and https://stackoverflow.com/a/7214312/14868997

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, using [an `ORDER BY` clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) at the end of the aggregation.

Note that joining everything together will probably get a cartesian product. You need to pre-aggregate, rather than just throwing `DISTINCT` at everything. Then you can remove the outer `GROUP BY`.

```sql
SELECT
    m.media_id, m.name, m.path, m.original_name, m.description, m.privacy, m.size, m.type, m.file_type, m.file_size, 
    m.width, m.height, m.date_created, m.date_uploaded, m.media_set_id,
    r.rating,
    c.comments,
    t.tags
FROM media m
JOIN users u USING (user_id) 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      array_agg(t.tag) filter (where t.tag is not null) as tags 
    FROM media_tags mt
    JOIN tags t USING (tag_id) 
    WHERE mt.media_id = m.media_id
) t ON 1=1
LEFT JOIN ratings r using (media_id, user_id) 
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT
      jsonb_agg(
        jsonb_build_object(
          'comment', c.comment,
          'parent_id', c.parent_id,
          'user_id', c.user_id,
          'date_updated', c.date_updated
        )
        ORDER BY c.date_updated
      ) filter (where c.comment is not null and c.date_deleted is null)
        as comments
    FROM comments c
    WHERE c.media_id = m.media_id
) c ON 1=1
WHERE u.user_id = 'b14c1548-d433-4bc2-9059-9091262e7305'
  AND m.date_deleted IS NULL
  AND m.privacy != 'support' 
ORDER BY
  date(m.date_created) DESC,
  m.date_created ASC,
  m.date_uploaded ASC;
```