# How to convert json string to dictionary and save order in keys?

Tags: python, json

I have problem when I want to convert json string to Python dictionary. I have string like

```
 s={"name":{"Saban:Saulic"},"price":{"koncert:1000"} ....}
```

when I write something like

```
tags=json.loads(s)
```

I gtet dictionary but order of keys is not the same like in string ( it is not name, price ...). How to convert json string to dictionary and save order in keys ?

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered, which is fine because normally you access the entries *by key* and if you have to iterate over the elements, the order does usually not matter. Btw, `s` is neither a string nor a dictionary not valid JSON if it was a string. It looks like you are after a different structure, such as an array of objects: `[{"name": "...", "price": "..."}, ...]`. If you provide some explanation for *why* you need the keys in order and provide a correct example, then we can help you better.

Comment: There is not really such a thing as "order of keys" in a `dict`. You can iterate over them one at a time, but there is no control over what order you get them in.

Comment: I think [this previous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python) question here on Stackoverflow provides an answer.

Answer (score 22):

Since [Python 2.7](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) you have [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) module from [`collections`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html)

This kind of dictionary preserves the insertion order of elements.

From Python docs:

> `json.load(fp[, encoding[, cls[, object_hook[, parse_float[,
>   parse_int[, parse_constant[,     object_pairs_hook[, **kw]]]]]]]])`
>
> Deserialize fp (a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a
>   JSON document) to a Python object.
>
> If the contents of fp are encoded with an ASCII based encoding other
>   than UTF-8 (e.g. latin-1), then an appropriate encoding name must be
>   specified. Encodings that are not ASCII based (such as UCS-2) are not
>   allowed, and should be wrapped with codecs.getreader(encoding)(fp), or
>   simply decoded to a unicode object and passed to loads().
>
> object_hook is an optional function that will be called with the
>   result of any object literal decoded (a dict). The return value of
>   object_hook will be used instead of the dict. This feature can be used
>   to implement custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class hinting).
>
> object_pairs_hook is an optional function that will be called with the
>   result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs.
>   The return value of object_pairs_hook will be used instead of the
>   dict. This feature can be used to implement custom decoders that rely
>   on the order that the key and value pairs are decoded (for example,
>   collections.OrderedDict() will remember the order of insertion). If
>   object_hook is also defined, the object_pairs_hook takes priority.

I think you could use object_pairs_hook parameter with [`collections.OrderedDict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects)

```
tags=json.loads(s, object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict)
```