# flask request.json order

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, flask

I get JSON data submitted to my api (built with Flask) endpoint and I need that data to be exported to excel but the problem is that once my api receives the data and loads it with *request.json* the the "body" part of data is scrambled - not in the same order I receive it which completely breaks my table headings not to mention the needed ouput excel format.

Including below the raw JSON data I receive to my api

```
{
"data": {
    "header": [
        "date,group.groupname,user.NameSurname,forwarding_number,reciver_number,CallerNameSurname,alert,connection,call_summ"
    ],
    "body": [
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:14",
            "connection": "00:00:53",
            "call_summ": "00:01:07"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:27",
            "connection": "00:00:25",
            "call_summ": "00:00:52"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:16",
            "connection": "00:01:00",
            "call_summ": "00:01:16"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Arvīds Boļesko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055001",
            "reciver_number": "66055001",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:22",
            "connection": "00:00:52",
            "call_summ": "00:01:14"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:18",
            "connection": "00:00:09",
            "call_summ": "00:00:27"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:09",
            "connection": "00:01:59",
            "call_summ": "00:02:08"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:08",
            "connection": "00:02:14",
            "call_summ": "00:02:22"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:04",
            "connection": "00:00:01",
            "call_summ": "00:00:05"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Arvīds Boļesko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055001",
            "reciver_number": "66055001",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:57",
            "connection": "00:01:26",
            "call_summ": "00:02:23"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:05",
            "connection": "00:02:23",
            "call_summ": "00:02:28"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:06",
            "connection": "00:00:44",
            "call_summ": "00:00:50"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Romāns Tiščenko",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:08",
            "connection": "00:02:43",
            "call_summ": "00:02:51"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:05",
            "connection": "00:01:13",
            "call_summ": "00:01:18"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:09",
            "connection": "00:00:01",
            "call_summ": "00:00:10"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "administration",
            "user.NameSurname": "Ieva Sproģe",
            "forwarding_number": "67783165",
            "reciver_number": "67783165",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:06",
            "connection": "00:01:30",
            "call_summ": "00:01:36"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:06",
            "connection": "00:00:50",
            "call_summ": "00:00:56"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "administration",
            "user.NameSurname": "Ieva Sproģe",
            "forwarding_number": "67783165",
            "reciver_number": "67783165",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:04",
            "connection": "00:02:00",
            "call_summ": "00:02:04"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "user.NameSurname": "Roberts Neijs",
            "forwarding_number": "66055003",
            "reciver_number": "66055003",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:07",
            "connection": "00:00:26",
            "call_summ": "00:00:33"
        },
        {
            "date": "2013-01-08",
            "group.groupname": "administration",
            "user.NameSurname": "Ieva Sproģe",
            "forwarding_number": "67783165",
            "reciver_number": "67783165",
            "CallerNameSurname": false,
            "alert": "00:00:04",
            "connection": "00:00:13",
            "call_summ": "00:00:17"
        }
    ],
    "footer": [
        ",,,,,,7,8,9"
    ],
    "filename": "outGoingAnswered.xls"
}
}
```

As I said, once this is read into the api with *request.json* the data within each "row" of "body" is scrambled - the order is broken. It should be as written in the header.

I've tried to load it using a different json library but the outcome is the same, the loaded data in not in the same order as it was given. I'm completely clueless as to why it would happen that way and it's making my life really difficult as I'm relatively new to Python.

I should mention that I cannot match the keys to header columns as the headers could have less keys than in the "body" "row".

As an example output I can offer the "scrambled version" of slightly different posted JSON data:

```
{
"data": {
    "body": [
        {
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "connection": "00:01:28",
            "call_summ": "00:01:42",
            "CallerNameSurname": "false",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "user.NameSurname": "Arnolds Apels",
            "date": "2012-12-13",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "alert": "00:00:14"
        },
        {
            "group.groupname": "customerService",
            "connection": "00:01:33",
            "call_summ": "00:01:45",
            "CallerNameSurname": "false",
            "forwarding_number": "66055002",
            "user.NameSurname": "Arnolds Apels",
            "date": "2012-12-13",
            "reciver_number": "66055002",
            "alert": "00:00:12"
        },
        {
            "group.groupname": "administration",
            "connection": "00:00:30",
            "call_summ": "00:00:33",
            "CallerNameSurname": "false",
            "forwarding_number": "67783165",
            "user.NameSurname": "Ieva Sproģe",
            "date": "2012-12-13",
            "reciver_number": "67783165",
            "alert": "00:00:03"
        }
    ],
    "header": [
        "date,group.groupname,user.NameSurname,forwarding_number,reciver_number,CallerNameSurname,alert,connection,call_summ"
    ],
    "footer": [
        "false,false,user.NameSurname,forwarding_number,reciver_number,CallerNameSurname,alert,connection,call_summ"
    ],
    "filename": [
        "asdasda.xls"
    ]
}
}
```

And for good measure adding the excel exporting code:

```
r = request.json
data = r['data']
if data:
    # Initialize excel export
    excel = Workbook()
    sheet = excel.add_sheet('Report')

    ## Excel headers

    # Setup font styling
    font = Font()
    font.name = 'Arial'
    font.bold = True

    # Setup cell border styling
    borders = Borders()
    borders.bottom = 1
    borders.right = 1

    # Setup formating style
    style = XFStyle()
    style.font = font
    style.borders = borders

    # Write headers
    header = data['header'][0]
    headers = header.split(',')
    h = 0
    for col in headers:
        if col == 'false':
            col = ''
        sheet.write(0, h, col, style)
        h += 1

    # Write body
    rows = data['body']
    i = 1
    for row in rows:
        x = sheet.row(i)
        y = 0
        for key, value in row.iteritems():
            x.write(y, value)
            y += 1
        i += 1

    # Write footer
    footer = data['footer'][0]
    footers = footer.split(',')
    f = 0
    for col in footers:
        if col == 'false':
            col = ''
        sheet.write(i, f, col)
        f += 1

    # Setup column widths
    if h > f:
        cols = h
    else:
        cols = f
    a = 0
    while a < cols:
        sheet.col(a).width = 5000
        a += 1

    # Get report filename
    filename = data['filename'][0]

    # Setup report path
    path = "/path/to/exports/" + filename

    # Save the report
    excel.save(path)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python dictionaries are *unordered*, as are JSON objects. The behaviour you see is normal.

If you need to retain ordering, don't use a `dict()` but a list up tuples instead:

```
   [
       ["date", "2013-01-08"],
       ["group.groupname", "customerService"],
       ["user.NameSurname", "Romāns Tiščenko"],
       ["forwarding_number", "66055002"],
       ["reciver_number", "66055002"],
       ["CallerNameSurname", false],
       ["alert", "00:00:14"],
       ["connection", "00:00:53"],
       ["call_summ", "00:01:07"]
   ],
   # ... etc.
```

*Or* you could also use the `data['header'][0]` string to read the body `dict()` values in order, since that is already ordered for you:

```
rows = data['body']
i = 1
for row in rows:
    x = sheet.row(i)
    y = 0
    for col in headers:
        x.write(y, row.get(col, ''))
        y += 1
    i += 1
```

Comment: Oh my god, I feel really stupid for not properly reading pythons dict documentation :( now I do tho, thanks a lot for the insanely fast response! In the end I stuck with the second version since I have no control on what is posted to the API.

Comment: I haven't testet it, but this answer might be helpful for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/6921760/1154535