# simplejson returns values not in order

Tags: python, django, json, simplejson

When working with `simplejson` in Django, I sometimes need to send the information strictly in order.

```
values = {"entry1":"value1","entry2":"value2","entry3":"value3"}
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(values),content_type="application/json")
```

That's what it returns

```
{"entry2": "value2", "entry3": "value3", "entry1": "value1"}
```

But I want it to returns this instead:

```
{"entry1":"value1","entry2":"value2","entry3":"value3"}
```

How can I send the information in order in `simplejson`?

Comment: it's a dictionnary. it doesn't have an order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I sometimes need to send the information strictly in order.

Don't use a dictionary then, use a list of tuples:

```
values = [("entry1", "value1"), ("entry2", "value2"), ("entry3", "value3")]
```

Dictionaries *and* JSON objects do not have a set order. Neither will preserve your input order, nor are they required to.

To quote the [JSON RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4627):

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs [...]

and the Python [`dict.items()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) documentation:

> Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions.

Comment: @jh314 answer seems to be working as well. What's more advisable? Using a list or `sort_keys=True`?

Comment: @Jerry: If you need the keys to be returned in sorted order, then use `sort_keys`. **However**, that does not guarantee that the consumer of the JSON data will not ignore the order of the object keys. If order is important, then use a list as it preserves order.

Comment: @Jerry: If your keys are *not* provided in sorted order, then `sort_keys` will still alter the ordering for you, of course. `{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2, 'eggs': 'ham'}` will be returned in the order `bar`, `eggs`, `foo` for example.

Comment: As a footnote, the main point of `sort_keys` is to generate stable output (e.g. for testing, or to avoid nuking caches etc -- extra important in recent Python versions that use a random hash seed), not to deal with decoders that don't implement the JSON spec correctly.  If you control both sides of your application, fix the consumer.

Comment: **This shouldn't be the accepted answer.** JSON objects do have a set order, namely as defined by the ordering of the elements. You're correct in that Python's `dict` doesn't have a guaranteed ordering, however `OrderedDict` does. See @pygeek's answer for how it can be used.

Comment: @bouke: the [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) disagrees with you: *An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value pairs*. Do *not* confuse the order of a single serialisation with a set ordering. The client that deserialises on the other side is perfectly in its right to *ignore* that order.

Answer (score 2):

The traditional way of solving this issue is by using 2-dimensional tuple/list, as suggested by Martjin Pieters.

The more Pythonic way of accomplishing this is by using OrderedDict, however.

For similar question/solution see:
[Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python)

For OrderedDict documentation see: http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sort_keys=True` option in dumps:

```
simplejson.dumps(values, sort_keys=True)
```

which will print out your dictionary with the keys in sorted order.  However, dictionaries are inherently unordered, so when you give the dictionary as a parameter to `HttpResponse`, the results won't be in order.

Answer (score 0):

This not problem with `simplejson`, its the behavior of `dict` in python. `dict`s are not ordered, so you can't really predict in what order they will come.

You can reformat your data to get that in order as:

```
values = [ {"entry1":"value1"}, { "entry2":"value2"} ,{"entry3":"value3"} ]
```

or

```
values = [ {"key":"entry1", "value":"value1"},
           {"key":"entry2", "value":"value2"},
           {"key":"entry3", "value":"value3"}
         ]
```

Comment: Well, it's not just dicts -- JSON objects are unordered so an implementation that relies on order when reading is broken.  From http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt: 
"An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
boolean, null, object, or array."