# Iterating over JSON object in python

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration

I have my `JSON` code below being stored in `jso` variable.

```
jso = {
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever I'm trying to fetch the data or iterate over the `JSON Object`, it's printing the data in the reverse order i.e `object` first and then the other parameters.

For eg. I execute:

```
>>> for k,v in jso.iteritems():
...     print v
...
```

AND THE OUTPUT I GOT:

**OUTPUT GETTING**

```
{'GlossList': {'GlossEntry': {'Abbrev': 'ISO 8879:1986', 'GlossDef': {'GlossSeeAlso': ['GML', 'XML']}, 'GlossSee': 'markup'}}, 'title': 'S'}
```

It can be seen that though `'title':'S'` was written before the `'GlossList' Object` still the data is printing in the reverse order. I mean it should have:

**OUTPUT EXPECTED**

```
{ 'title': 'S', 'GlossList': {'GlossEntry': {'Abbrev': 'ISO 8879:1986', 'GlossDef': {'GlossSeeAlso': ['GML', 'XML']}, 'GlossSee': 'markup'}}}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python are unordered collections:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary).

But, if you've loaded json from the string, you can load it directly to the [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), see:

- [Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python)

Comment: It's also important to note that this concept extends to JSON.  "An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."

Comment: Thanks @alecxe ! But I'm unable to use `isinstance(v,(list))` or `isinstance(v,(str))` for checking the entry being a list/string when I'm iterating over OrderDict

for k,v in my_ordered_dict.iteritems():
...     print k,v


GlossDiv OrderedDict([(u'title', u'S'), (u'GlossList', OrderedDict([(u'GlossEntry', OrderedDict([(u'Abbrev', u'ISO 8879:1986'), (u'GlossDef', OrderedDict([(u'GlossSeeAlso', [u'GML', u'XML'])])), (u'GlossSee', u'markup')]))]))])

>>>isinstance(v,(list)) #isinstance(v,(str))

Comment: @VarunMalhotra This requirement is not in your question. Edit your question to explain what you need.

Comment: @VarunMalhotra remember, that you have nested ordered dicts. `v` in `for k,v in my_ordered_dict.iteritems()` is an `OrderedDict` too.