# How to convert an OrderedDict into a regular dict in python3

Tags: python, type-conversion, ordereddictionary

I am struggling with the following problem:
I want to convert an `OrderedDict` like this:

```
OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
```

into a regular dict like this:

```
{'method': 'constant', 'data':1.225}
```

because I have to store it as string in a database. After the conversion the order is not important anymore, so I can spare the ordered feature anyway.

Thanks for any hint or solutions,

Ben

Comment: `repr(dict(OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])))`?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
>>> dict(OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')]))
{'data': '1.225', 'method': 'constant'}
>>>
```

However, to store it in a database it'd be much better to convert it to a format such as JSON or Pickle. With Pickle you even preserve the order!

Comment: you can [preserve order with `json` too](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6921699/4279).

Comment: Thanks, and also for the advice using pickle. I would use pickle and I actually do it in other places, but some constraints demand using a dict converted to string.

Comment: Would converting ordereddict to dict loose order?

Comment: Yes it does lose order.

Comment: json.loads also in python < 3.0 does not preserve the order.

Comment: Please note that thos does not work for nested OrderedDictionary data, @thiruvenkadam should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @WindUpLordVexxos I disagree, the OP's data wasn't nested, so this answers his question. And going through JSON for this purpose isn't very efficient...

Comment: @ThiefMaster Your method works. But for the OPs data. I'd argue that the structure outlined in his question could have been a dummy example, and that we can't assume that anyone reading this question would have his exact same structure. When answering these questions, we must assume a generalistic stance agnostic of the OPs specifics.

Answer (score 102):

Even though this is a year old question, I would like to say that using `dict` will not help if you have an ordered dict within the ordered dict. The simplest way that could convert those recursive ordered dict will be

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
input_dict = OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('recursive', OrderedDict([('m', 'c')]))])
output_dict = json.loads(json.dumps(input_dict))
print output_dict
```

Comment: Nice move for a script etc., i.e. _I don't care about performance for this one-off task, just gimme dicts so I can pretty print them_

Answer (score 10):

It is easy to convert your `OrderedDict` to a regular `Dict` like this:

```
dict(OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')]))
```

If you have to store it as a string in your database, using JSON is the way to go.  That is also quite simple, and you don't even have to worry about converting to a regular `dict`:

```
import json
d = OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
dString = json.dumps(d)
```

Or dump the data directly to a file:

```
with open('outFile.txt','w') as o:
    json.dump(d, o)
```

Answer (score 7):

If you are looking for a recursive version without using the `json` module:

```
def ordereddict_to_dict(value):
    for k, v in value.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            value[k] = ordereddict_to_dict(v)
    return dict(value)
```

Comment: Doesn't handle lists in data.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what seems simplest and works in python 3.7

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])
d2 = dict(d)  # Now a normal dict
```

Now to check this:

```
>>> type(d2)
<class 'dict'>
>>> isinstance(d2, OrderedDict)
False
>>> isinstance(d2, dict)
True
```

NOTE: This also works, and gives same result -

```
>>> {**d}
{'method': 'constant', 'data': '1.225'}
>>> {**d} == d2
True
```

As well as this -

```
>>> dict(d)
{'method': 'constant', 'data': '1.225'}
>>> dict(d) == {**d}
True
```

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

You can use "dict_constructor" parameters.

`xmltodict.parse(text, attr_prefix='',`**`dict_constructor=dict`**`)`

Comment: How do *XML* and *parse* enter the picture?

Comment: Thanks!  Although it doesn't address the question, I came here looking to convert OrderedDict generated by `xmltodict.parse()`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data structure might contain internal (nested) `OrderedDict` instances, you should leverage Python's builtin [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) mechanism.

You can override copying behavior for `OrderedDict` via Python's [`copyreg`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copyreg.html#module-copyreg) module (also used by [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)). Then you can use Python's builtin [`copy.deepcopy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) function to perform the conversion.

```py
import copy
import copyreg
from collections import OrderedDict

def convert_nested_ordered_dict(x):
    """
    Perform a deep copy of the given object, but convert
    all internal OrderedDicts to plain dicts along the way.

    Args:
        x: Any pickleable object

    Returns:
        A copy of the input, in which all OrderedDicts contained
        anywhere in the input (as iterable items or attributes, etc.)
        have been converted to plain dicts.
    """
    # Temporarily install a custom pickling function
    # (used by deepcopy) to convert OrderedDict to dict.
    orig_pickler = copyreg.dispatch_table.get(OrderedDict, None)
    copyreg.pickle(
        OrderedDict,
        lambda d: (dict, ([*d.items()],))
    )
    try:
        return copy.deepcopy(x)
    finally:
        # Restore the original OrderedDict pickling function (if any)
        del copyreg.dispatch_table[OrderedDict]
        if orig_pickler:
            copyreg.dispatch_table[OrderedDict] = orig_pickler
```

Merely by using Python's builtin copying infrastructure, this solution is superior to all other answers presented here, in the following ways:

- Works for arbitrary data hierarchies, including nested `OrderedDict`s.
- Works for more than just JSON data.
- Does not require you to implement special logic for each possible element type (e.g. `list`, `tuple`, etc.)
- `deepcopy()` will properly handle duplicate objects within the collection:

  ```py
  x = [1,2,3]
  d = {'a': x, 'b': x}
  assert d['a'] is d['b']

  d2 = copy.deepcopy(d)
  assert d2['a'] is d2['b']
  ```

  Since our solution is based on `deepcopy()` we'll have the same advantage.
- This solution also converts *attributes* that happen to be `OrderedDict`, not only collection elements:

  ```py
  class C:
      def __init__(self, a):
          self.a = a

      def __repr__(self):
          return f"C(a={self.a})"

  c = C(OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')]))
  print("original: ", c)
  print("converted:", convert_nested_ordered_dict(c))
  ```

  ```
  original:  C(a=OrderedDict([(1, 'one'), (2, 'two')]))
  converted: C(a={1: 'one', 2: 'two'})
  ```

Answer (score -2):

Its simple way

```
>>import json 
>>from collection import OrderedDict

>>json.dumps(dict(OrderedDict([('method', 'constant'), ('data', '1.225')])))
```

Answer (score -2):

A version that handles nested dictionaries and iterables but does not use the `json` module. Nested dictionaries become `dict`, nested iterables become `list`, everything else is returned unchanged (including dictionary keys and strings/bytes/bytearrays).

```py
def recursive_to_dict(obj):
    try:
        if hasattr(obj, "split"):    # is string-like
            return obj
        elif hasattr(obj, "items"):  # is dict-like
            return {k: recursive_to_dict(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        else:                        # is iterable
            return [recursive_to_dict(e) for e in obj]
    except TypeError:                # return everything else
        return obj
```