# multiple OrderedDict to dictionary from python

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I currently my OrderedDict like below.

```
d = [OrderedDict([('id', u'570c737e87f8dc15788790b7'), ('name', u'Murgh ')]), OrderedDict([('id', u'570c737e87f8dc15788790b6'), ('name', u'Mushroom')])]
```

But here i need to convert this to normal dictionary format like below.

```
{"id": "570c737e87f8dc15788790b7","name": "Murgh"
  },

{
"id": "570c737e87f8dc15788790b6","name": "Mushroom"
  }
```

How to do this from python.

Comment: This question does not really seem to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166749/how-to-convert-an-ordereddict-into-a-regular-dict-in-python3, since the data structure in the question is not an OrderedDict, but a list of OrderedDicts, and the desired output also seems to be different.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a new `dict` with data from each of your `OrderedDicts` like this:

```
dicts = [dict(_) for _ in d]
```

Alternatively, to get a dict with ids as keys and names as values:

```
users = { od['id']:od['name'] for od in d }
```

Comment: @LutzHorn: Correct. I hope the updated answer reflects that

Comment: @LutzHorn thank.But still its display as list dict i want only dict.

Comment: @user1335606: Ah, I get it. A dictionary can contain each key only once. So you can't have the key 'id' multiple times. The desired output you gave in your question also is a list/tuple of dicts. Could you update your question to show how the dict should look?

Comment: actually i am writing web services above result i got from the serializers.py. so in Postman is display as a List dict which is causing a problem.