# Is there a way to store xml sub tags in a list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml.etree

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of BeautifulSoup's find_all feature, using xml.etree module.
For some reasons, we are not allowed to use bs4 packages and thus Beautiful soup is out of the equation.
Are there any way where i can search for a specific tag, and then store each line of the tag till it's end?

```
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <State name="Singapore"><State name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </State>
```

I need something like, get the details of State tag in a list.

```
[<State name="Singapore">,<rank>4</rank>,.....,'</state>']
```

unfortunately, when I try to iter through the XML file, it gives me a object over the exact contents. and .attrib returns a dict for me.

Comment: Your example isn't valid XML.

Comment: What is preventing you from building your list from what your "iter" provides you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `xmlToDict` and iterate through the keys? You can use `json.dumps` on the OrderedDict ([like so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27373027/10381765)) if you just want a regular dict, but here's an example assuming you want to preserve order.

This is assuming you fix your XML by removing that duplicate `<State>` tag and use a closing `</Data>` tag.

```
import xmltodict
from collections import OrderedDict

def listRecursive(d, key):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, OrderedDict):
            for found in listRecursive(v, key):
                yield found
        if k == key:
            yield v

with open('PATH\\TO\\xmlFile.xml') as fd:
    xmlDict = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())

states = []
for result in listRecursive(xmlDict, 'State'):
    states.append(result)
states = states[0]
```

Here's a `pprint` of the results, assuming you add another State after Singapore called `NewState`

```
[OrderedDict([('@name', 'Singapore'),
              ('rank', '4'),
              ('year', '2011'),
              ('gdppc', '59900'),
              ('neighbor',
               OrderedDict([('@name', 'Malaysia'), ('@direction', 'N')]))]),
 OrderedDict([('@name', 'NewState'),
              ('rank', '7'),
              ('year', '2020'),
              ('gdppc', '99999'),
              ('neighbor',
               [OrderedDict([('@name', 'Unknown1'), ('@direction', 'S')]),
                OrderedDict([('@name', 'Unknown2'), ('@direction', 'N')])])])]
```