# Convert OrderedDict to normal dict

Tags: python

I have a list of OrderedDicts like this:

```
input = [OrderedDict([('id', 'mp-1'), ('name', 'John')]), OrderedDict([('id', 'mp-2'), ('name', 'Peter')])]
```

How can I convert it to a list of normal dicts like this

```
output = [{'id': 'mp-1', 'name': 'John'}, {'id': 'mp-2', 'name': 'Peter'}]
```

Comment: `list(map(dict,input))`

Comment: The `dict` constructor can take a list of pairs as input so you can pass the `OrderedDict` to the `dict` constructor

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert an OrderedDict into a regular dict in python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20166749/how-to-convert-an-ordereddict-into-a-regular-dict-in-python3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict` constructor:

```
>>> output = [dict(i) for i in input]
>>> output
[{'id': 'mp-1', 'name': 'John'}, {'id': 'mp-2', 'name': 'Peter'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
output = []
for odict in input:
    output.append(dict(odict))
```

Its not crazy fast, but its readable and good enough.