# How to json.loads as list instead of dictionary in Python

Tags: python

I have problem in reading json from file using python. The data are stored in dictionary that makes unsorted. I want to store the data in list variable to be in right sequence.

```
flookup = open('lookup.json') 
self.tags = json.loads(flookup.read())        
flookup.close()
```

self.tags contains data not ordered based on lookup.json file

```
{
  "JournalTitle": "Journal Title",
  "PubCode": "Pub Code",
  "UniqueDocumentID": "Unique Document ID"
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking, but this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python

Comment: You can load json as a list but it has to be a list. In this case you need to load as a dict and transform to a list. with something like `[v for +, v in myjsondict.items()]`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import collections, json
data = '{"a":1, "b": 2}'
print json.JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict).decode(data)
```

prints

```
OrderedDict([(u'a', 1), (u'b', 2)])
```

(Though it seems a bit strange to require such a thing. If order is significant, JSON data should be in an array.)

Comment: Or, the list of keys being accessed, in those sections of the code where order matters, is fed in from an array (and therefore ordered).