# I have dictionary need to fill it into tree, how to?

Tags: python, recursion, tree

I have dictionary like this, need to fill it into tree like scheme in array or DB for example:

```
a = {"seasons": "episodes", "peka": {"lol": "wow", "kek": {"wtf": "is this"}}, "ololo": "wololo"}
```

key `"seasons"` have own `ID = 1`, `Parent_ID = NONE` 
and value `"episode"` have its own `ID = 2` and `Parent_ID = 1` , 
and the same with other item of dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> /!\ WARNING the order in a dictionnary is not guaranteed see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965870/convert-ordereddict-to-normal-dict-preserving-order)

```
a = { 
      "seasons": "episodes", 
      "peka": {"lol": "wow", "kek": {"wtf": "is this"}}, 
      "ololo": "wololo"
    }
```

The object a is dictionnary the order of (key, value) is not guaranteed, that is to say random if you do `print(a)`, you have :

```
{'ololo': 'wololo', 'peka': {'kek': {'wtf': 'is this'}, 'lol': 'wow'}, 'seasons': 'episodes'}
```

It is another order.

To keep the same order, copy/past this type in the file `file.json` and user
OrderedDict.

**file.json**:

```
{ 
  "seasons": "episodes", 
  "peka": {"lol": "wow", "kek": {"wtf": "is this"}}, 
  "ololo": "wololo"
}
```

Here your solution:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict
from pprint import pprint

with open('file.json', 'r') as filename:
    a = json.load(filename, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)


def build_item(_id, parent_id, value):
    return {'ID': _id, 'Parent_ID': parent_id, 'Value': value}


def dfs(_id, root, tree):
    _id += 1
    flat_tree = [build_item(_id, None, root)]
    stack = [(_id, tree)]
    while len(stack) != 0:
        parent_id, tree = stack.pop(0)
        if isinstance(tree, dict):
            for value in tree.keys():
                _id += 1
                flat_tree.append(build_item(_id, parent_id, value))
                stack.append((_id, tree[value]))
        else:
            value = tree
            _id += 1
            flat_tree.append(build_item(_id, parent_id, value))
    return _id, flat_tree


def convert_dict_to_flat_tree(d):
    flat_trees = list()
    _id = 0
    for root, tree in d.items():
        _id, flat_tree = dfs(_id, root, tree)
        flat_trees.extend(flat_tree)
    return flat_trees


flat_tree = convert_dict_to_flat_tree(a)

pprint(flat_tree)
```

Output:

```
[{'ID': 1, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'seasons'},
 {'ID': 2, 'Parent_ID': 1, 'Value': 'episodes'},
 {'ID': 3, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'peka'},
 {'ID': 4, 'Parent_ID': 3, 'Value': 'lol'},
 {'ID': 5, 'Parent_ID': 3, 'Value': 'kek'},
 {'ID': 6, 'Parent_ID': 4, 'Value': 'wow'},
 {'ID': 7, 'Parent_ID': 5, 'Value': 'wtf'},
 {'ID': 8, 'Parent_ID': 7, 'Value': 'is this'},
 {'ID': 9, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'ololo'},
 {'ID': 10, 'Parent_ID': 9, 'Value': 'wololo'}]
```

Comment: i am getting this output:{'ID': 1, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'seasons'}
{'ID': 2, 'Parent_ID': 1, 'Value': 'episodes'}
{'ID': 3, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'peka'}
{'ID': 4, 'Parent_ID': 3, 'Value': 'lol'}
{'ID': 5, 'Parent_ID': 3, 'Value': 'kek'}
{'ID': 6, 'Parent_ID': 5, 'Value': 'wtf'}
{'ID': 7, 'Parent_ID': 6, 'Value': 'is this'}
{'ID': 8, 'Parent_ID': 7, 'Value': 'wow'}
{'ID': 9, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'ololo'}
{'ID': 10, 'Parent_ID': 9, 'Value': 'wololo'}

Comment: I change the output to have nice output with `pprint`. Is the result correct ?

Comment: In your output value= "wow" have correct id and parent_id (6 ,5) , i have "wow" as id =8 and parent_id = 7

Comment: It is normal the order in a dictionnary is not guarantee see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965870/convert-ordereddict-to-normal-dict-preserving-order

Comment: @RonBurgundy it ok for you ?

Comment: i have made changes but but still this output [{'ID': 1, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'seasons'},
 {'ID': 2, 'Parent_ID': 1, 'Value': 'episodes'},
 {'ID': 3, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'peka'},
 {'ID': 4, 'Parent_ID': 3, 'Value': 'lol'},
 {'ID': 5, 'Parent_ID': 3, 'Value': 'kek'},
 {'ID': 6, 'Parent_ID': 5, 'Value': 'wtf'},
 {'ID': 7, 'Parent_ID': 6, 'Value': 'is this'},
 {'ID': 8, 'Parent_ID': 7, 'Value': 'wow'},
 {'ID': 9, 'Parent_ID': None, 'Value': 'ololo'},
 {'ID': 10, 'Parent_ID': 9, 'Value': 'wololo'}]

Comment: I understand, I fixed that ;). Is it ok now ?

Comment: Thank you so much :) really appreciate it , have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
a = {"seasons": "episodes", "peka": {"lol": "wow", "kek": {"wtf": "is this"}}, "ololo": "wololo"}

_id = {}

def newid():
    id = _id.setdefault('foo', 0)
    _id['foo'] += 1
    return id

def flat(dic, parent):
    for k,v in dic.items():
        id = newid()
        yield (id, parent, k, v if not isinstance(v, dict) else None)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
           for tup in flat(v, id):
               yield tup

print list(flat(a, newid()))
```

Which prints:

```
[(1, 0, 'seasons', 'episodes'), 
 (2, 0, 'ololo', 'wololo'), 
 (3, 0, 'peka', None), 
 (4, 3, 'kek', None), 
 (5, 4, 'wtf', 'is this'), 
 (6, 3, 'lol', 'wow')]
```

These are tuples in the form (ID, Parent ID, Key, Value?). I would have prefer to output E(ID, Parent ID, Key) V(ID, Value).

Comment: I need every item(k,v) to be printed out and with ID and Parent_ID