# Python OrderedDict: sort by tuple order?

Tags: python

So I have this dictionary, which I'm converting to OrderedDict.  On conversion, I'd like to sort the OrderedDict by the order in which its keys appear in a separate tuple.  Any other values I'd like to append to the end of the OrderedDict.  Nonexistent keys in the ordering tuple should be ignored.

I think I have most of it, but I'm having trouble wrapping my brain around the lambda sorted functions.  Can you help me iron it out?

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
    'spam': 'tasty',
    'subtitle': 'A Subtitle',
    'title': 'Test Title',
    'foo': 'bar',
}

key_order = ('title', 'subtitle', 'non_in_dictionary')
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda ???? ))
```

should produce `ordered_dict`:

```
{
    'title': 'Test Title',
    'subtitle': 'A Subtitle',
    'spam': 'tasty',
    'foo': 'bar',
}
```

Comment: What order do you intend for the keys that aren't in your `key_order` tuple?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, my issue is I don't know *what* to try; I'm at a loss.

Comment: @tzaman, I'm not picky.  Alphabetical, I suppose.  I'm bringing in the data actually from a JSON file (with inherent order, although JSON doesn't care), so I'm putting `spam` before `foo` for that reason.

Comment: @niteshade only just seen you mention *I'm bringing in the data actually from a JSON file* - look at using `object_pairs_hook` when loading the JSON - see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python) for examples. That'd be a far more efficient solution if you know your attributes are in the correct order in the JSON data.

Comment: @JonClements, thanks very much, looks good.  I'll keep this in mind for future reference.  Most of the JSON elements are in the correct order, but I still need to pull a few to the top, so I'll have some sorting to do anyways.  I really appreciate it regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another method which is a bit simpler than sorting is to create an `OrderedDict` from the titles, then update the `OrderedDict` from your original `dict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
    'spam': 'tasty',
    'subtitle': 'A Subtitle',
    'title': 'Test Title',
    'foo': 'bar',
}

key_order = ('title', 'subtitle')
od = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in key_order)
od.update(d)
```

Or as [tzaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257465/tzaman) suggests in comments, as the values will always be set on the following update, you can construct the original `OrderedDict` with:

```
od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(key_order)
od.update(d)
```

Comment: A little simpler: `od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(key_order)` -- the values don't matter.

Comment: @Tzaman ahhh... clever - the values will get updated from the following `.update` :)

Comment: @Sir_FZ not for the initial creation. They'll get set during the `update` call.

Comment: Good catch. Though I thought you meant they didn't matter at all

Comment: would this be appreciably slower than ordering the OD at creation?  This function will be chewing through HUGE dictionaries, so I'd like  it as efficient as possible.  (that's why I assumed the lambda sort would be best.)

Comment: @niteshade: It shouldn't be appreciably slower; if anything, I'd expect it to be faster.

Comment: @niteshade dictionary updates are fast - I'd personally expect it to out perform creating an index lookup, then sorting the `dict`s items against that lookup using a lambda... thus creating a `list` that gets put into an OD. Where the `key_order` is a large subset of the original `dict` then they'll be unnecessary replacements - but that'll be on key updates so should be fast and avoid the memory cost of creating a list.

Comment: @niteshade this will almost certainly be faster, particularly with the `fromkeys` formulation. The first pass will just set the key order, and the second pass will iterate over your source dictionary once; no sorting at all so it'll theoretically be `O(n)` instead of `O(n lg n)` which is a big win for huge dicts. `sorted` will also be creating an intermediate copy which is bad memory-wise.

Comment: OK, excellent.  Thanks.  The one problem I'm having is handling keys not in the dict (not your fault, I know... I should edit the question).  Like, if `title` doesn't exist in the `dict`.  Can you think of any easy way to fix?

Comment: @niteshade `od = OrderedDict.fromkeys(filter(d.__contains__, key_order))`. Or in the original version: `od = OrderedDict((k, d[k]) for k in key_order if k in d)`

Answer (score 0):

```
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(dict.items(),
               key=lambda x: key_order.index(x[0])if x[0] in key_order else 10e10 ))
```

This uses a key of the index of the given item in the key order. If it isn't found, it uses a large number instead, putting it at the end. It produces the following `OrderedDict`:

```
OrderedDict([('title', 'Test Title'), ('subtitle', 'A Subtitle'), ('foo', 'bar'), ('spam', 'tasty')])
```

`foo` is before `spam` because the original dictionary had an arbitrary order.

Answer (score -1):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {
    'spam': 'tasty',
    'subtitle': 'A Subtitle',
    'title': 'Test Title',
    'foo': 'bar',
}

key_order = ('title', 'subtitle')
key_order = OrderedDict((k, i) for i, k in enumerate(key_order))
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(d.iteritems(), key=lambda k: key_order.get(k[0], float("inf"))))
```

Use `items()` instead of `iteritems()` in python 3.

Comment: This produces an error. `key_order` is a `tuple` and thus has no method `get`.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 look closer. `key_order` is an `OrderedDict`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 That part is fine, they are converting it to an `OrderedDict` on the next line, the issue is the syntax error.

Comment: Add parenthesis around `k, i`.

Comment: I'd also use `float('inf')` instead of `sys.maxint` but since the size of a container won't exceed that - it's more a matter of style - I just tend to find it more explicit that I really do mean *after everything* else

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the reassignment. Of course, I then put that into the interpreter and it complained about the other error. Then it complained about `sys.maxint` which doesn't exist in Python 3.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 neither does `iteritems()` I'll use @Jon Clements' suggestion for `maxint` and point out to use `items()` instead in python 3

Comment: re: `dict`; I'll change that in the example.