# extract record by csv and filtering by date

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file where each record is a LinkedIn contact. I have to recreate another csv file where each contact it was reached only after a specific date (ex all the contact that are connected to me after 1/04/2017).
So this is my implementation:

```
def import_from_csv(file):
    key_order = ("FirstName","LastName","EmailAddress","Company","ConnectedOn")
    linkedin_contacts = []
    with open(file, encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            single_person = {"FirstName": row["FirstName"], "LastName": row["LastName"],
                             "EmailAddress": row["EmailAddress"], "Company": row["Company"],
                             "ConnectedOn": parser.parse(row["ConnectedOn"])}
            od = OrderedDict((k, single_person[k]) for k in key_order)
            linkedin_contacts.append(od)
    return linkedin_contacts
```

the first script give to me a list of ordered dict, i dont know if the way i used to achive the correct order is good, also seeing some example (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30515632/python-ordereddict-sort-by-tuple-order)) i'm not using the od.update method, but i dont think i need it, is it correct?

Now i wrote a second function to filter the list:

```
def filter_by_date(connections):
    filtered_list = []
    target_date = parser.parse("01/04/2017")
    for row in connections:
        if row["ConnectedOn"] > target_date:
            filtered_list.append(row)
    return filtered_list
```

Am I doing this correctly?

Is there a way to optimize the code? Thanks

Comment: it is ok for your issue ?  ...

Comment: yes, both solution works and are more compact, but maybe i prefer use dateutils, more easy and immediate for me, because looking the cvs. the dates have this format: 9/25/2014

Comment: also the  datetime.strptime("01/04/2017", '%Y/%m/%d').date() give me an error: ValueError: time data '01/04/2017' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d' but of course changing the string order things works, but with dateutil i dont have to worry about the format, i think

Comment: Don't use date at the end I updated see my edited post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First point: you don't need the `OrderedDict` at all, just [use a `csv.DictWriter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter) to write the filtered csv.

```
    fieldnames = ("FirstName","LastName","EmailAddress","Company","ConnectedOn")
    with open("/apth/to/final.csv", "wb") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames)
        writer.writeheader() 
        writer.writerows(filtered_contacts)
```

Second point: you don't need to create a new dict from the one yielded by the csv reader, just update the ConnectedOn key in place :

```
def import_from_csv(file):
    linkedin_contacts = []
    with open(file, encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader=csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            row["ConnectedOn"] = parser.parse(row["ConnectedOn"])
            linkedin_contacts.append(row)
    return linkedin_contacts
```

And finally, if all you have to do is take the source csv, filter out records on `ConnectedOn` and write the result, you don't need to load the whole source in memory, create a filtered list (in memory again) and write the filtered list, you can stream the whole operation:

```
def filter_csv(source_path, dest_path, date):
    fieldnames = ("FirstName","LastName","EmailAddress","Company","ConnectedOn")
    target = parser.parse(date)

    with open(source_path, "rb") as source, open(dest_path, "wb") as dest:
        reader = csv.DictReader(source)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(dest, fieldnames)
        # if you want a header line with the fieldnames - else comment it out
        writer.writeheaders()

        for row in reader:
            row_date = parser.parse(row["ConnectedOn"])
            if row_date > target:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

And here you are, plain and simple.

NB : I don't know what "parser.parse()" is but as others answers mention, you'd probably be better using the `datetime` module instead.

Answer (score 1):

For filtering you could use `filter()` function:

```
def filter_by_date(connections):
    target_date = datetime.strptime("01/04/2017", '%Y/%m/%d').date()
    return list(filter(lambda x: x["ConnectedOn"] > target_date, connections))
```

And instead of creating simple `dict` and then fill its values into `OrderedDict` you could write values directly to the `OrderedDict`:

```
for row in reader:
    od = OrderedDict()
    od["FirstName"] = row["FirstName"]
    od["LastName"] = row["LastName"]
    od["EmailAddress"] = row["EmailAddress"]
    od["Company"] = row["Company"]
    od["ConnectedOn"] = datetime.strptime(row["ConnectedOn"], '%Y/%m/%d').date()
    linkedin_contacts.append(od)
```

If you know date format you don't need `python_dateutil`, you could use built-in `datetime.datetime.strptime()` with needed format.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't precise the format string.

Use :

```
from datetime import datetime

format = '%d/%m/%Y'
date_text = '01/04/2017'

# inverse by datetime.strftime(format)
datetime.strptime(date_text, format)  


#....
# with format as global
for row in reader:
   od = OrderedDict()
   od["FirstName"] = row["FirstName"]
   od["LastName"] = row["LastName"]
   od["EmailAddress"] = row["EmailAddress"]
   od["Company"] = row["Company"]
   od["ConnectedOn"] = strptime(row["ConnectedOn"], format)
   linkedin_contacts.append(od)
```

Do:

```
def filter_by_date(connections, date_text):
        target_date = datetime.strptime(date_text, format) 
        return [x for x in connections if x["ConnectedOn"] > target_dat]
```