# Why weblate import of JSON does not respect the original order?

Tags: weblate

I've just installed Weblate to host our translation projects.
It's working fine, but the import process of our JSON files is creating the strings in a different order than the original ones.

The result is that nerby messages are not the same than in the original files; the strings are mixed, and so it will be very difficult for translators to work in that order.

Why is the original order (present in JSON files) not respected?
Is it possible to respect it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that [translate-toolkit](https://github.com/translate/translate) which is library that Weblate uses doesn't respect it. It should be quite easy to adjust [jsonl10n](https://github.com/translate/translate/blob/master/translate/storage/jsonl10n.py) storage to [use OrderedDict](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921760/225718) to fix this.

Update: This seems to be fixed as of translate-toolkit 1.14.0-rc1.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. Unfortunately, I do not know python.
But I saw that dwaynebailey made some work on orderedDict 9 days ago on jsonl10n.py
Do you think that it matches with what I need?

Comment: Indeed that seems to be what was needed :-).

Comment: Yes, its woking now.
Thanks a lot for your help! :)