# Same JSON Strings when converting to json string cross platform

Tags: java, python, json

If I have a json String {"k":"v","a":"b"}.

If I convert it into a json Object and then back to String in Java let say using Gson library and store it in some database.

And Also I convert  it into json Object and back to String in Python , it is possible that I get the String as {"a":"b","k":"v"} , though json object will be same but now I cannot do a string match as the order is changed.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: You could use [`OrderedDict`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6921760/887828) I think.

Comment: Why not do the comparison of the objects?

Comment: @Kennet , the database supports string comparison only , comparison is not inside JVM or python.

Comment: @Hacketo, I don't have the luxury to parse the json as , the database does string comparison and it does not support json, I am saving json into database from python as well as java and hence the problem

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that order of json object keys will be same.

Json object is **unordered** by specefication: http://json.org/

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

If you want some order, you should use json array instead of json object.

> An array is an ordered collection of values.

*see also:* [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST-ARCH/ECMA-262,%203rd%20edition,%20December%201999.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the keys are always in sorted order when the JSON is serialized to the database. In Python you would write:

```
json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True)
```

With GSON this is harder to do, you may need to use a different library.

Comment: will it sort nested json also or else this solution will not work

Comment: @Peter in Python, yes. Java is going to be the problem.