# Preserving order AND maintaining all keys when loading JSON?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ordereddictionary, defaultdict

Using the approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6921760/1389110), I pass `OrderedDict` as `object_pairs_hook` when loading a nested JSON file, to preserve order.

Order is preserved, and this is fine for *most* of the JSON object. But there are parts of the JSON (at the lowest level of nesting), which look like:

`"In Content" : {
    "Sulvo" : "abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile",
    "Sulvo" : "abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level2",
    "Sulvo" : "abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level3",
    "Adsense" : ""
  },`

And when processed, only one of these identical keys gets preserved:

`OrderedDict([(u'Sulvo', u'homeepiphany.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level3'),
(u'Adsense', u'')])),`

I know that we can have a dictionary which has multiple items of the same key name with a `defaultdict`. The following doesn't work though, and even it it did, I presume we would gain the keys but lose the order, so we'd be no better off:

`j = json.load(open('he.json'), object_pairs_hook=defaultdict)`

Is it possible to maintain order *AND* preserve all keys in one go?

Python 2.7.12

Answer (score 3):

If you look at the [docs for `json.load`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load), they outline what the `object_pairs_hook` parameter does:

> `object_pairs_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the result of any object literal decoded with an ordered list of pairs. The return value of `object_pairs_hook` will be used instead of the `dict`.

All you need to do is write a function that, given a list of `(key, value)` pairs, constructs your object.

One approach would be to do nothing and just pass the items list straight through without constructing a dictionary:

```
def handle_mapping(items):
    return items
```

Then, your JSON is parsed like so:

```
[(u'In Content',
  [(u'Sulvo', u'abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile'),
   (u'Sulvo', u'abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level2'),
   (u'Sulvo', u'abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level3'),
   (u'Adsense', u'')])]
```

If you do want to merge the values of duplicate keys into a list, you can use `OrderedDict`:

```
def handle_mapping(items):
    d = OrderedDict()
    duplicate_keys = set()

    for key, value in items:
        # So [('k', 'v')] becomes {'k': 'v'}
        if key not in d:
            d[key] = value
        else:
            # So [('k', 'v1'), ('k', 'v2')] becomes {'k': ['v1', 'v2']}
            if key not in duplicate_keys:
                duplicate_keys.add(key)
                d[key] = [d[key]]

            d[key].append(value)

    return d
```

Then, you'd object would be parsed as:

```
OrderedDict([(u'In Content',
              OrderedDict([(u'Sulvo',
                            [u'abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile',
                             u'abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level2',
                             u'abc.com_336x280_he-inlinecontentmobile_level3']),
                           (u'Adsense', u'')]))])
```

Comment: That's one hell of an answer. I got as far as the `handle_mapping()` suggestion. It was surprising to me that passing just the json file to `json.load()` - i.e. not specifying an `object_pairs_hook` -  also resulted in loss of items, whereas passing the dummy function resulted in them being preserved. Will try your full solution tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: @Pyderman: In Python, `dict([('a', 1), ('a', 1)]) == {'a': 1} == {'a': 1, 'a': 1}`, since having duplicate keys in a dictionary doesn't make sense (what would `d['a']` do?). JavaScript (the J in **J**SON) does the same thing. You have to tell Python to use something other than a dictionary to hold your elements if your JSON is weird like yours.