# Maintaining key order of JSON file when loading in Python 2.6

Tags: python, json

I am using Python 2.6 to load a JSON string. I want to maintain the key order of the string when I load. I tried using the answer here: [Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python)

and I made sure to import `simplejson as json` since I am on Python 2.6, but I am still receiving this error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_pairs_hook'
```

What am I missing?

Here is code (truncated):

```
import simplejson as json
import ordereddict
theJson = json.loads('{valid json}', object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
```

same error if I use `import json` instead of simplejson

Comment: @AChampion ok. even if I don't use it, same error.

Comment: Sorry `object_pairs_hook` was added in 3.1.

Comment: What version of *simplejson* do you have installed?

Comment: @cpburnz simplejson 2.0.9. I see object pairs hook support was added in 2.1.0. Darn. Is there another way? i don't have the rights to upgrade simplejson in my constrained environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could provide an updated local copy of *simplejson*.

Download the *simplejson* source:

```
git clone https://github.com/simplejson/simplejson.git
```

Compile *simplejson*:

```
cd simplejson
python setup.py build
```

Package *simplejson* as an *egg* (zipped Python package):

```
python setup.py bdist_egg
```

The *simplejson* egg will be located at:

```
dist/simplejson-<version>-<python>-<os>-<arch>.egg
```

Where *<version>* is the *simplejson* version, *<python>* is the Python version, *<os>* is the operating system, and *<arch>* is the processor architecture. On my machine this resulted in:

```
dist/simplejson-3.10.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg
```

Copy the *simplejson* egg to somewhere accessible (this could simply be the local directory of your application). Now in your Python application, you have to tell Python where it can find the new version of *simplejson*:

```
import sys

SIMPLEJSON_EGG = 'path/to/simplejson-....egg'
sys.path.insert(1, SIMPLEJSON_EGG)

import simplejson
```