# Load json into OrderedDict in python 2.6 - unexpected keyword error

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to load json file to an OrderedDict following mjhm's answer in [Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python).  I'm starting with just a json string for simplicity and the code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import simplejson as json
import ordereddict

testjson='{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }'

my_ordered_dict = json.loads(testjson, object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
```

However, I get the following error when running the above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./l.py", line 8, in <module>
    my_ordered_dict = json.loads(testjson, object_pairs_hook=ordereddict.OrderedDict)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 318, in loads
    return cls(encoding=encoding, **kw).decode(s)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'object_pairs_hook'
```

I'm on python 2.6.6 and simplejson version is 2.0.9.  Is there a way I can use to load json file into an OrderedDict?  The aim is to read json, add some entries and then print it out preserving the order of original json file.

**Edit:**

After upgrading simplejson it still does not work - different version of simplejson is reported by pip and by the script.  I added the following to the script:

```
print "simplejson version: " + json.__version__
print "simplejson path: " + json.__file__
```

It prints:

```
simplejson version: 2.0.9
simplejson path: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson/__init__.pyc
```

However, pip reports:

```
$ pip show simplejson
DEPRECATION: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.6
Name: simplejson
Version: 3.10.0
Summary: Simple, fast, extensible JSON encoder/decoder for Python
Home-page: http://github.com/simplejson/simplejson
Author: Bob Ippolito
Author-email: bob@redivi.com
License: MIT License
Location: /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages
Requires:
```

Both report the same location for simplejson module and both seem to be installed:

```
$ ls -ld /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson*
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 May  9 15:29 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  9 15:29 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson-2.0.9-py2.6.egg-info
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 May  9 09:10 /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/simplejson-3.10.0-py2.6.egg-info
```

How do I make sure that python uses 3.10.0 version and not the 2.0.9?

Comment: Update your `simplejson`.

Answer (score 0):

[`object_pairs_hook` was added to `simplejson` in version 2.1.0.](https://simplejson.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#simplejson.load) Your version is too old; update it.

Comment: Tried `pip install -Iv simplejson 2.1.0` but got: No matching distribution found for 2.1.0.  Not sure what version to install that will work with python 2.6.6.  Do I need to worry about compatibility issues?

Comment: `sudo pip install simplejson --upgrade` did the trick: Successfully installed simplejson-3.10.0

Comment: Got the same `unexpected keyword argument` error with simplejson version  3.6.5.  Works only after upgrading to the latest - 3.10.0.  Also, had to use --proxy=<proxy address> with pip install command.

Comment: Actually, it's not working.  I'll update my question.