# How to Combine two JSON files?

Tags: python, json, join

I've two json objects, I 'm figuring out a way on how to merge them in python

```
y={"success":"true"}
x={"0":"740","1":"747","2":"883","3":"750","4":"769"}
```

I need the final result in the following manner

```
{"success":"true",
  "data":{
       "0":"740",
       "1":"747",
       "2":"883", 
       "3":"750", 
       "4":"769"
         }
              }
```

I am trying to append it, but its showing some error. Help me with the code in python.

Comment: these are just 2 dicts. why not just `y['data'] = x`?

Comment: It shows the following error when I tried that

Comment: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: I've tried to append x into y,not working!:(

Comment: If they are json (which means they are probably string) then first convert both of them to python dict using `json.loads` and then merge those dicts and then finally convert them back to json using `json.dumps`

Comment: then `x` is a `str` and not a dict (as your example shows). you need to decode it using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads).

Comment: x is not a string, I converted a data frame to json

Comment: its not a dict for adding keys

Comment: Your last comment is confusing. What do you mean?

Comment: Check [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html#pandas-dataframe-to-json) link. If you used the usual function then the return is surely a string as mentioned in the doc. So your two converted data frames should be string not dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your input seem to be strings and not dictionaries. you need to convert them to dicts using [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads):

```
import json

y = '{"success":"true"}'
x = '{"0":"740","1":"747","2":"883","3":"750","4":"769"}'

res = json.loads(y)
res['data'] = json.loads(x)

print(res)
```

if you need the output as string again, use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps):

```
res_str = json.dumps(res)
```

if you insist on having the ouput sorted:

```
res_str = json.dumps(res, sort_keys=True)
```

Comment: Getting output as   {"data": {"1": "747", "0": "740", "3": "750", "2": "883", "4": "769"}, "success": "true"}, why is 1 coming infront of 0?

Comment: dictionaries are unordered. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary) for example.

Comment: Because python dicts, by definition are  not ordered. If you need to have ordered dict you can either sort it on keys or use something like [ordereddict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python) in which case the conversion becomes more complex of course.

Comment: @SandeepRajamahendravarapu: added a way how you can sort the output with `json.dumps`. but that will only concern the json string; not the dict itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do `y["data"] = x`

```
y={"success":"true"}
x={"0":"740","1":"747","2":"883","3":"750","4":"769"}

y["data"] = x
```

Comment: error:'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: In that case, look at [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44562838/8160345).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that they are strings and not python dicts. So here is what you can do

```
y='{"success":"true"}'
x='{"0":"740","1":"747","2":"883","3":"750","4":"769"}'

import json
dict1 = json.loads(x)
dict2 = json.loads(y)

dict2['data'] = dict1

result = json.dumps(dict2)
print result
```

The code above gives you this

```
{"data": {"1": "747", "0": "740", "3": "750", "2": "883", "4": "769"}, "success": "true"}
```

If you want to have the structure in the json string preserved you can look into [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python). That will make the decoding a little bit more complex.

Comment: {"1": "747", "0": "740", "3": "750", "2": "883", "4": "769", "data": {"success": "true"}}    wrong output!

Comment: Changed the code a bit to fit the output. I also mentioned a link to use ordered dicts to be be created directly from json string in my comment to other answer. Let me know if it helps.