# sqlalchemy/psycopg2 desreializes my jsons as dicts but doesn't preserve order

Tags: json, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have a psql query that returns a json object. I fetch this query with `results.fetchall()` and I get the json properly as a dict.
however, as I'm in python 3.4, not yet in 3.6, the objects' order is not preserved in the dict. I saw there's [a way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python) to use `OrderedDict` to keep the order of the json but I'm not sure how to tell sqlalchemy/psycopg2 to use it.

can anybody help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/postgresql.html#sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.JSON), you must provide a custom deserializer when creating your engine:

```
from functools import partial
import json, collections

engine = create_engine(
    ...,
    json_deserializer=partial(
        json.loads, 
        object_pairs_hook=collections.OrderedDict),
    )
```

Comment: thanks a lot @donkopotamus
any suggestion how to make this deserializer used only for a particular `fetchhall`?

Comment: @akiva For a given fetchall you won't necessarily know the connection that is being used (since there is a connection pool).  You may need to instead push a custom json deserializer on at the `psycopg2` level (using [`psycopg2.extras.register_default_json`](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.register_default_json)) and then pop it off.  That's what sqlalchemy is doing in the engine call