# json.loads() doesn't keep order

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have formatted my String to look like `JSON` so I could do `json.loads` on it. When I printed on the screen it turned out it messed up the order. I know that Python dictonaries are not ordered but is there ANY way to keeps this order? I really need to keep it. Thanks!

Comment: Well it does not make any sense in the first place since both Python and JSON dictionaries are unordered.

Comment: I have read that there is something like `OrderedDict` in Python, wouldn't that be helpful?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict-in-python

Comment: *"formatted my String to look like JSON"* - That sounds like you're doing it in a bad way...

Comment: @StefanPochmann why do you say that? :) I needed to do that to use `json.loads` on it

Comment: @soommy12 Because it sounds like you're running your own formatting code instead of just using `json.dumps`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann I have a String cut from `JavaScript` code, it was looking similar to `JSON` but I needed to format it to use `json.loads`. I think this is the only way. But if you have any other idea let me know, maybe I can improve my code

Comment: @soommy12 Cutting from JavaScript code also sounds odd... If you have the data in JavaScript, I'd say have the JavaScript convert it to JSON. Then again, I don't really know what you're doing and I don't know much about JavaScript.

Comment: @StefanPochmann well, trust me this is the only way I can do my project, I do not need to tell you exactly what I am doing :P question was about keeping order in `json.loads()` only and problem is solved, no need for more discussion

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Both JSON en Python dictionaries (those are JSON objects) are unordered. So in fact it does not makes *any* sense to do that, because the JSON encoder can change the order.

You can however define a custom JSON decoder, and then parse it with that decoder. So here the dictionary hook willl be an `OrderedDict`:

```
from json import JSONDecoder
from collections import OrderedDict

customdecoder = JSONDecoder(object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Then you can decode with:

```
customdecoder.decode(your_json_string)
```

This will thus store the items in an `OrderedDict` instead of a dictionary. But be aware - as said before - that the [order of the keys of JSON objects is unspecified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202095/67579).

Alternatively, you can also pass the hook to the `loads` function:

```
from json import loads
from collections import OrderedDict

loads(your_json_string, object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

> **Update**: as of [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7), a dictionary retains insertion order. So if one uses [python-3.7](/questions/tagged/python-3.7), the standard `json.load` and `json.loads` should work fine. Note however that a JSON object is still unordered, so that the JavaScript end can load/dump the object in any order.

Comment: what about `json.loads(string, object_pairs_hook_=OrderedDict)` ?

Comment: @soommy12: sure, but this is in my opinion a bit against the encapsulation principle. Now you can pass the decoder as an argument, etc.

Comment: Okey, I got the point, thank you very much! :)

Comment: As of 3.7, python dicts are ordered