# How to get the keys of dictionary with its original order

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

[image]

I have a dictionary loading from json. How I can get a list of key with the same order.

like [1, 10, 100, 101, 102, 11, 12 .......]

Looks like if I use .keys() it will change to some other order.

If I load this way, the order will be different.
[image]

Comment: Use a type that preserves order.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict)