# Parse an embedded object (JSON) into an ordered dictionary in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, ordereddictionary

I am looking to parse some JSON into a dictionary but need to preserve order for one particular part of the dictionary.

I know that I can parse the entire JSON file into an ordered dictionary (ex. [Can I get JSON to load into an OrderedDict?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921699/can-i-get-json-to-load-into-an-ordereddict)) but this is not quite what I'm looking for.

```
{
    "foo": "bar",
    "columns":
    {
        "col_1": [],
        "col_2": []
    }
}
```

In this example, I would want to parse the entire file in as a dictionary with the "columns" portion being an `OrderedDict`. Is it possible to get that granular with the JSON parsing tools while guaranteeing that order is preserved throughout? Thank you!

Comment: not sure why you don't want the complete result to be an OrderedDict, but if you don't care about efficiency too much, you could always do the following: `dict(json.loads("YOUR INPUT", object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict))` :-)

Comment: @BartVanLoon Thank you! I'm potentially fine with the entire thing being an `OrderedDict`. Would that guarantee the order of `columns` or would it end up being an `OrderedDict` with an orderless dictionary `columns` as a child? If that makes sense.

Comment: no, it will be an OrderedDict all the way down

Comment: @BartVanLoon thanks for all the help! Great information. I am a little new to Python so I appreciate your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

From the comments meanwhile, I gathered that a complete, nested OrderedDict is fine as well, but this could be a solution too, if you don't mind using some knowledge about the names of the columns:

```
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

def hook(partialjson):
    if "col_1" in partialjson:
        return OrderedDict(partialjson)
    return dict(partialjson)

result = json.loads("YOUR JSON STRING", object_hook=hook)
```

Hope this helps!