# Unintentional random order in a list

Tags: python, list

I am trying to build a list with data of a JSON object. However the order of the list does not match the oder of the JSON object and changes nearly everytime I run the code.

```
{
    "project":{
        "Projektnamen":{
            "Server":{
                "Server1":{
                    ...
                },
                "Server2":{
                    ...
                },
                "Server3":{
                    ...
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```py
with open('json_data.json') as json_file:
    # json CONFIG_JSON Konfigurationsdatei
    CONFIG_JSON = json.load(json_file)

for key in CONFIG_JSON["project"]["Projektnamen"]["Server"]:
    servernamen.append(key)
```

Expected result: servernamen = [Server1, Server2, Server3]

However the order always changes.
Last result: servernamen = [Server3, Server1, Server2]

Comment: probably before Python 3.6 array (or rather dictionary) doesn't have to keep order. If you need order then better keep it as list.

Comment: dictionary does not guarantee order.

Comment: @TheScientificMethod That information is out of date. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47881325/4014959 OTOH, the JSON specification doesn't require `{}` objects to retain order, so it's generally *not* wise to have a data flow that expects them to retain order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can import your JSON data already sorted by using [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#ordereddict-objects) and the arguments of `json.load`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import json


r = json.load(open('json_data.json'), object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads` deserializes JSON into a dictionary object, which is a hash table that is not ordered.

You can use `OrderedDict` from `collections` to sort keys.
Example

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'banana': 3, 'apple':4, 'pear': 1, 'orange': 2}
new_d = OrderedDict(sorted(d.items()))

print(new_d)
# OrderedDict([('apple', 4), ('banana', 3), ('orange', 2), ('pear', 1)])
```

Comment: Is there a way to load the JSON in order?

Comment: Solution added in response