# Using pprint for OrderedDicts when dict is made with two lists

Tags: python, dictionary, ordereddictionary, pprint

When I have `OrderedDict` created from two list and if I try to use `pprint` it's not working as expected, bur it works fine if I create `OrderedDict` normally.

Any additional steps needs to be taken to get expected output of each key value in separate line if OrderedDict is created with two list ?

```
import pprint
from collections import OrderedDict
```

### pprint does not work

```
l1 = [ 'a', 'b', 'x', 'd']
l2 = [ ['abc', 'def'], ['idk', 'jfk'], ['mnp'], ['oye oye']]
dic = OrderedDict(zip(l1, l2))
pprint.pprint(dic, width = 1)

OrderedDict([('a', ['abc', 'def']), ('b', ['idk', 'jfk']), ('x', ['mnp']), ('d', ['oye oye'])])
```

### Works !!!

```
dic2 = OrderedDict()
dic2 = {'a': 'abc', 'x' : 'xyz', 'b' : 'boy'}
pprint.pprint(dic2, width = 1)

{'a': 'abc',
 'b': 'boy',
 'x': 'xyz'}
```

Comment: Works with Python 3.5 though.

Comment: hmm .. I am on 2.7 :(

Comment: One more reason to use a current version. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the version that you think works, you are not printing a `OrderedDict`, but an ordinary `dict`. See that `dic2 = {'a': 'abc', 'x' : 'xyz', 'b' : 'boy'}` is an ordinary dict.

To create a `OrderedDict` from a `dict` you should have written:

```
dic2 = OrderedDict({'a': 'abc', 'x' : 'xyz', 'b' : 'boy'})
```

an the result would be the same as the `zip` version.

It seems that Python 2.7 doesnt support `pprint` from `OrderedDict`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4301069/5189607) for some workarounds.

Comment: ahh - I got it . I saw the post you mentioned but since it was 5 yrs back I thought bug would be fixed, anyways thanks for the pointer .. I would follow that link ..appreciate your help !!