# pprint() will not change width of output

Tags: python, python-3.x, pprint

tldr; I'm trying to use `__repr__()`  and `pprint()` to pretty-print a custom python class to the terminal, but the output width remains the same no matter what width I pass to `pprint()`.  I have seen the question [How can I make my class pretty printable in Python? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40828173/how-can-i-make-my-class-pretty-printable-in-python), but it doesn't explain why the *width* isn't changing in my case, even though pprint() successfully prints my custom class.

Here's my  `__repr__()` function.

```py
def __repr__(self):
    output = 'task(' + repr(self.name) + ', ' + repr(self.subtasks) + ')'
    return output
```

And here's the problem: when I try to test `pprint()` with the following loop,

```py
for width in [ 80, 20, 5 ]:
    print('WIDTH =', width)
    pprint(task_tree, width=width)
```

all outputs have the same width.

```
WIDTH = 80
task(root, [task(Top Level 1, [task(secondary, []), task(secondary b, []), task(secondary c, [])]), task(Top Level 2, []), task(Top Level 3, [])])
WIDTH = 20
task(root, [task(Top Level 1, [task(secondary, []), task(secondary b, []), task(secondary c, [])]), task(Top Level 2, []), task(Top Level 3, [])])
WIDTH = 5
task(root, [task(Top Level 1, [task(secondary, []), task(secondary b, []), task(secondary c, [])]), task(Top Level 2, []), task(Top Level 3, [])])
```

What could be going wrong?  How should I modify my class' `__repr__()` so that this works as expected, i.e. that pprint() prints representations of the class with widths of 80, 20, and 5 characters?

---

I based my approach on the following excerpt from [pprint — Pretty-Print Data Structures — PyMOTW 3](https://pymotw.com/3/pprint/index.html),  where it's demonstrated how to use `pprint()` with arbitrary classes.

> ### Arbitrary Classes
>
> The `PrettyPrinter` class used by `pprint()` can also work with custom classes, if they define a `__repr__()` method.
>
> pprint_arbitrary_object.py
>
> ```py
> from pprint import pprint
>
>
> class node:
>
>     def __init__(self, name, contents=[]):
>         self.name = name
>         self.contents = contents[:]
>
>     def __repr__(self):
>         return (
>             'node(' + repr(self.name) + ', ' +
>             repr(self.contents) + ')'
>         )
>
>
> trees = [
>     node('node-1'),
>     node('node-2', [node('node-2-1')]),
>     node('node-3', [node('node-3-1')]),
> ]
> pprint(trees)
> ```
>
> The representations of the nested objects are combined by the `PrettyPrinter` to return the full string representation.
>
> ```py
> $ python3 pprint_arbitrary_object.py
>
> [node('node-1', []),
>  node('node-2', [node('node-2-1', [])]),
>  node('node-3', [node('node-3-1', [])])]
> ```

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question earlier?

Comment: yes, but I made enough edits that I thought I should delete the original and create a new question.

Comment: You should edit the original and request that it be reopened.

Comment: I'm working from memory, but I don't see any significant differences.

Comment: I don't think the pretty printer will break the representation of a single object across multiple lines.

Comment: Since your `__repr__` method combines all the subtasks into a single representation string, the pretty printer doesn't know anything about the nesting sdtructure.

Comment: I changed the order of my explanation, made reference to another SO question, and edited the passage from PMOTW to reference the python 3 pmotw instead of python 2.  Should I edit and undelete the original?

Comment: Too late now, remember it for the future.

Comment: ok will do thank you.

Comment: The example you show doesn't have it splitting up the `node` objects, it's just collecting them into a list and pretty-printing the list.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229998/discussion-between-david-and-barmar).

Comment: I have tried splitting up the node objects individually  with `subtasks = ''.join([repr(s) for s in self.subtasks])`,  and then setting output with `output = 'task(' + repr(self.name) + ', ' + subtasks + ')'`, but it still doesn't change the width.

Comment: That's still a single string when you join it.

Comment: `pprint()` doesn't know that the string was constructed by combining multiple objects. It's just a string when `repr()` returns it.

Comment: I closed the last question as a duplicate, but for some reason you say the solutions there won't work for you. Did you try the first answer of adding to the `_dispatch` table?

Comment: If none of them work, then I don't think there's a solution. `pprint()` isn't really designed to be extensible to custom aggregate objects.