Python3 custom pretty printer for derived class objects?
I have attempted to make a pretty printer for a number of objects deriving from a class; but I have arrived at some behavior that puzzles me - I hope I can get some help to understand (and fix) it. Consider the following code:
from collections import OrderedDict
import pprint

class Basis(OrderedDict):
  def __init__(self):
    self["name"] = "Basis"
  def __str__(self):
    return "{{ {} }}".format(
      ", ".join(["'{}': {}".format(k, "'{}'".format(v) if type(v)==str else v) for k,v in self.items()])
    )
  #def __repr__(self):
  #  return self.__str__()

class ClassOne(Basis):
  def __init__(self):
    self["name"] = "ClassOne"
    self["keyA"] = "ValueA"

class ClassTwo(Basis):
  def __init__(self):
    self["name"] = "ClassTwo"
    self["keyB"] = "ValueB"

class Collector(Basis):
  def __init__(self):
    pass #self["name"] = "Collector"

class Collector2(Basis):
  def __init__(self):
    self["name"] = "Collector2"


class ODPPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
  # based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/40828173 ; https://stackoverflow.com/q/3258072 ;
  _dispatch = pprint.PrettyPrinter._dispatch.copy()
  def _pprint_odtype(self, object, stream, indent, allowance, context, level): # _pprint_yourtype ; _pprint_operation
    print("ODPPrinter", f"{object=}", flush=True)
    items = object.items()
    if not items:
      print("not items: {}".format(items), flush=True)
      stream.write(repr(object))
      return
    cls = object.__class__
    print("ODPPrinter", f"{cls=}", flush=True)
    stream.write(cls.__name__ + "(")
    self._format_items(
      items, stream, indent + len(cls.__name__), allowance + 1, context, level
    )
    stream.write(')')
  print(f"# ODPPrinter {hex(id(Basis.__repr__))=}", flush=True)
  _dispatch[Basis.__repr__] = _pprint_odtype

def main():
  col = Collector()
  col["c1"] = ClassOne()
  col2 = Collector2()
  col2["c2"] = ClassTwo()
  odpp = ODPPrinter()
  print("\n** col", f"{col.__repr__=}\n{hex(id(col.__repr__))=}\n", "col printout:\n", odpp.pformat(col), "\n", flush=True)
  print("\n** col2", f"{col2.__repr__=}\n{hex(id(col2.__repr__))=}\n", "col2 printout:\n", odpp.pformat(col2), "\n", flush=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()

If you run the code as-is, then: class Basis has no custom __repr__() method; class Collector has pass in its init, while class Collector2 initializes a key/value par in its init; if you call the code, you get this printout:
$ python3 test.py
# ODPPrinter hex(id(Basis.__repr__))='0x21580c40bd0'

** col col.__repr__=<method-wrapper '__repr__' of Collector object at 0x00000215814a3840>
hex(id(col.__repr__))='0x215814dc190'
 col printout:
 Collector([('c1', ClassOne([('name', 'ClassOne'), ('keyA', 'ValueA')]))])

ODPPrinter object=Collector2([('name', 'Collector2'), ('c2', ClassTwo([('name', 'ClassTwo'), ('keyB', 'ValueB')]))])
ODPPrinter cls=<class '__main__.Collector2'>

** col2 col2.__repr__=<method-wrapper '__repr__' of Collector2 object at 0x00000215814a3940>
hex(id(col2.__repr__))='0x215814dc190'
 col2 printout:
 Collector2(('name', 'Collector2'),
           ('c2', ClassTwo([('name', 'ClassTwo'), ('keyB', 'ValueB')])))

So, when class Basis has no custom __repr__(), ODPPrinter._pprint_odtype() got only triggered for Collector2 (which did not just pass, but initialized a key/value in its __init__()), even though both col and col2 report their repr to be "<method-wrapper '__repr__' of Collector* object"
If I now uncomment the repr method of class Basis:
  def __repr__(self):
    return self.__str__()

... and re-run the code, I get:
$ python3 test.py
# ODPPrinter hex(id(Basis.__repr__))='0x183c8ec1620'

** col col.__repr__=<bound method Basis.__repr__ of { 'c1': { 'name': 'ClassOne', 'keyA': 'ValueA' } }>
hex(id(col.__repr__))='0x183c8eafb40'
 col printout:
 { 'c1': { 'name': 'ClassOne', 'keyA': 'ValueA' } }


** col2 col2.__repr__=<bound method Basis.__repr__ of { 'name': 'Collector2', 'c2': { 'name': 'ClassTwo', 'keyB': 'ValueB'
} }>
hex(id(col2.__repr__))='0x183c8eafbc0'
 col2 printout:
 { 'name': 'Collector2', 'c2': { 'name': 'ClassTwo', 'keyB': 'ValueB' } }

So, when class Basis does have custom __repr__(), both col and col2 report their repr to be "<bound method Basis.__repr__ of {...}", regardless of if they just pass their init or not - and I'd expect _dispatch[Basis.__repr__] = _pprint_odtype to establish the triggering of _pprint_odtype precisely when Basis.__repr__ is reported by the type of __repr__() of the respective object - but here, ODPPrinter._pprint_odtype() never triggers?
So, my question is - is there a way to set up the pretty printer, so it always runs on objects derived from (in this case) class Basis - regardless of whether they just pass (or actually initialize keys/properties) in their __init__, and regardless of whether the Basis.__repr__() method has been overloaded or not?

You can copy the PrettyPrinter._format method into your derived class and remove the if len(rep) > max_width: check (or just replace it by if True:).
